# Difference between string object and string literal

Tags: java, string, string-literals

What is the difference between

```
String str = new String("abc");
```

and

```
String str = "abc";
```

Comment: Succinct answer: a string object is a **variable**; a string literal is a **constant** (a fixed sequence of characters between quotation marks).  [More details](http://mindbugzz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/what-is-difference-between-strings-and.html)

Comment: A String *literal* is a String *object*, but a String *object* is not necessarily a String *literal*.  And once assigned to a reference variable, it's all but impossible to tell if a given String object is a *literal* or not.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of something it doesn't duplicate at all.  Not that it's a great question, but others have this one listed as a duplicate correctly, and the duplicate list should end in somethings that's really duplicate.

Comment: I got this question wrong on a Sybex exam because I said it was false: `All String literals are automatically instantiated into a String object.` .  The exam seems to think its always true, even if a literal is interned to an already existing object?

Answer (score 225):

When you use a string literal the string can be [*interned*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), but when you use `new String("...")` you get a new string object.

In this example both string literals refer the same object:

```
String a = "abc"; 
String b = "abc";
System.out.println(a == b);  // true
```

Here, 2 different objects are created and they have different references:

```
String c = new String("abc");
String d = new String("abc");
System.out.println(c == d);  // false
```

In general, you should use the string literal notation when possible. It is easier to read and it gives the compiler a chance to *optimize* your code.

Comment: In practice you generally see `new String(...)` used not because someone wants the behavior described here but because they are unaware that strings are immutable.
So you see things like `b = new String(a); b = b.substring(2);`
rather than just `b = a.substring(2)` as maybe the author is under the impression that the substring method will modify the instance on which it's called.
Also while it's true `"abc" == "abc"` I'd say that _in general_ code that relies on this rather than using equals(...) is being clever and prone to confusing things (static final "constants" being an exception).

Comment: @broofa: In what way can this be useful in JavaScript?

Comment: What is the importance of this concept ? Saving memory ?

Comment: You can use `new String("...").intern()` too...

Comment: When you use a string literal the string *is* interned, by the rules of the JLS. There is no 'chance' about it. The compiler is obliged to pool these literals.

Answer (score 90):

A *String literal* is a Java language concept. This is a String literal:

```
"a String literal"
```

A *String object* is an individual instance of the `java.lang.String` class.

```
String s1 = "abcde";
String s2 = new String("abcde");
String s3 = "abcde";
```

All are valid, but have a slight difference. `s1` will refer to an *interned* String object. This means, that the character sequence `"abcde"` will be stored at a central place, and whenever the same literal `"abcde"` is used again, the JVM will not create a new String object but use the reference of the *cached* String.

`s2` is guranteed to be a *new String object*, so in this case we have:

```
s1 == s2 // is false
s1 == s3 // is true
s1.equals(s2) // is true
```

Comment: Many, many languages have the concept of a String Literal :)

Comment: So does this means the literal String "abc" is still an object like `new String("abc")` and the only difference is that it is stored in the intern pool instead of the heap?

Comment: @yifei yes, that's what it means.

Comment: So it's mean `string literal is better` because it use same object again and instead of new space?

Comment: So in you case, the char arry 'abcde' referenced by s2 is located in heap not string pool? So if you create 100 String object like new String("abc"), in the heap, the abc will have 100 copy?

Comment: I checked, s1 and s2 has same hash and content, but still both are different when compared with `s1==s2`, why so?
And as asked by @liamxu, i tried to make 3 copies of s2, i.e. `s4 = new string("abcde");` and `s5 = new string("abcde");` but both have same hashcode.
Im less aware of how hash works actually, what `s1.hashcode()` returns?

Comment: is there only difference of concept of string pool and heap? As I read It is interesting to note that until Java 7, the pool was in the permgen space of the heap on hotspot JVM but it has been moved to the main part of the heap since Java 7 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14194112/2284107

Answer (score 42):

The long answer is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), so I'll give you the short one.

When you do this:

```
String str = "abc";
```

You are calling the `intern()` method on [String](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). This method *references an internal pool* of `String` objects. If the String you called `intern()` on already resides in the pool, then a reference to that `String` is assigned to `str`. If not, then the new `String` is placed in the pool, and a reference to it is then assigned to `str`.

Given the following code:

```
String str = "abc";
String str2 = "abc";
boolean identity = str == str2;
```

When you check for object identity by doing `==` (you are literally asking: do these two references point to the same object?), you get `true`.

However, you don't *need* to `intern()` `Strings`. You can force the creation on a new `Object` on the Heap by doing this:

```
String str = new String("abc");
String str2 = new String("abc");
boolean identity = str == str2;
```

In this instance, `str` and `str2` are references to different `Objects`, neither of which have been *interned*, so that when you test for `Object` identity using `==`, you will get `false`.

In terms of good coding practice: do *not* use `==` to check for String equality, use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: You're not really calling intern() by just referencing a literal. You're relying on the compiler having already pooled them and created the String object in the constant area.

Comment: EJB, since when does the compiler create objects? The compiled byte code might run 10 years later on a different machine. It is the job of the JVM to create String objects. And according to the machine language specification (3.10.5), `A string literal is a reference to an instance of class String`. The specification even promises that it will be the same instance across different classes and packages. You might be thinking of a "constant expression". The code `"Hello" + " World"` will be rewritten, by the **compiler**, to `"Hello World"`.

Comment: @MartinAnderson Since the [JLS required it to](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), which first happened back in 1995 if not before. The behaviour when encountering a string literal is (1) pooling within the class by the compiler, and (2) pooling within the JVM by the classloader. All these actions take place long before the string literal is 'encountered' by executing the line of code that references it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer only because of the explanation. Thanks for making this concept more clear.

Answer (score 40):

As Strings are immutable, when you do:

```
String a = "xyz"
```

while creating the string, the JVM searches in the pool of strings if there already exists a string value `"xyz"`, if so `'a'` will simply be a reference of that string and no new String object is created.

But if you say:

```
String a = new String("xyz")
```

you force JVM to create a new `String` reference, even if `"xyz"` is in its pool.

For more information read [this](http://javatechniques.com/public/java/docs/basics/string-equality.html).

Comment: the link is now broken, I guess it was this article : http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Answer (score 17):

`"abc"` is a literal String.

In Java, these literal strings are pooled internally and the same String instance of `"abc"` is used where ever you have that string literal declared in your code.  So `"abc" == "abc"` will always be true as they are both the same String instance.

Using the [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method you can add any string you like to the internally pooled strings, these will be kept in memory until java exits.

On the other hand, using `new String("abc")` will create a new string object in memory, which is logically the same as the `"abc"` literal. 
`"abc" == new String("abc")` will always be false, as although they are logically equal they refer to different instances.

Wrapping a String constructor around a string literal is of no value, it just needlessly uses more memory than it needs to.

Comment: "the internally pooled strings will be kept in memory until java exits".  I think that at least with modern JVM this is no longer valid, because the GC also collects unused objects in the perm area.  Can you confirm that ?

Answer (score 8):

String is a class in Java different from other programming languages. So as for every class the object declaration and initialization is

```
String st1 = new String();
```

or

```
String st2 = new String("Hello"); 
String st3 = new String("Hello");
```

Here, `st1`, `st2` and `st3` are different objects.

That is:

```
st1 == st2 // false
st1 == st3 // false
st2 == st3 // false
```

Because `st1`, `st2`, `st3` are referencing 3 different objects, and `==` checks for the equality in memory location, hence the result.

But:

```
st1.equals(st2) // false
st2.equals(st3) // true
```

Here `.equals()` method checks for the content, and the content of `st1 = ""`, `st2 = "hello"` and `st3 = "hello"`. Hence the result.

And in the case of the String declaration

```
String st = "hello";
```

Here, `intern()` method of `String` class is called, and checks if `"hello"` is in intern pool, and if not, it is added to intern pool, and if "hello" exist in intern pool, then `st` will point to the memory of the existing `"hello"`.

So in case of:

```
String st3 = "hello";
String st4 = "hello";
```

Here:

```
st3 == st4 // true
```

Because `st3` and `st4` pointing to same memory address.

Also:

```
st3.equals(st4);  // true as usual
```

Comment: @CaZbaN1         +1 for explaining the intern method intern() for determining whether the value exists on the Heap.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, there are two objects created.

In the second case, it's just one.

Although both ways `str` is referring to `"abc"`.

Comment: Can you explain me how to obj created in first case?

Comment: @GautamSavaliya
In the first case, one object will be created in the String pool to cache the String for further reuse in the code and another object will be created in the heap memory. You can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool for more details about String pool.

Answer (score 5):

Some disassembly is always interesting...

```
$ cat Test.java 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String abc = "abc";
        String def = new String("def");
    }
}

$ javap -c -v Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "Test.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method  #7.#16;  //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = String  #17;     //  abc
const #3 = class   #18;     //  java/lang/String
const #4 = String  #19;     //  def
const #5 = Method  #3.#20;  //  java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
const #6 = class   #21;     //  Test
const #7 = class   #22;     //  java/lang/Object
const #8 = Asciz   <init>;
...

{
public Test(); ...    

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   Stack=3, Locals=3, Args_size=1
    0:    ldc #2;           // Load string constant "abc"
    2:    astore_1          // Store top of stack onto local variable 1
    3:    new #3;           // class java/lang/String
    6:    dup               // duplicate top of stack
    7:    ldc #4;           // Load string constant "def"
    9:    invokespecial #5; // Invoke constructor
   12:    astore_2          // Store top of stack onto local variable 2
   13:    return
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answers already posted, also see [this](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/Journal200409.jsp#a1) excellent article on javaranch.

Answer (score 3):

According to [String class documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) they are equivalent.

Documentation for `String(String original)` also says that: *Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.*

Look for other responses, because it seems that Java documentation is misleading :(

Comment: -1 in some sense yes, in other sense no. So your answer is misleading.

Comment: They're absolutely not equivalent. One will construct a new string each time it's executed and one won't. The strings involved will be *equal*, but that doesn't mean the two expressions will behave exactly the same way.

Comment: So documentation lies :( Or maybe I do not understand two first paragraphs of String documentation.

Comment: @Michal: Yes, the documentation is pretty misleading. And that constructor *can* be useful in certain situations as it effectively "trims" the new string to size.

Comment: @Michał Niklas: +1 for the confusing Javadoc (as is very common with Java).  +1 because it reminds one to take everything written in the Javadocs with a huge grain of salt :)

Comment: I'm having trouble agreeing with some of the above comments. @Jon, @Michal: The doc doesn't say the strings are equal, just that `new()` ing a string is unnecessary. @Jon: Given your reputation I'm hesitant to question your answer, but I don't see any way a cloned String literal would in any way be "trimmed" compared to the original. The only reason I can imagine for using `new("literal")` would be to obtain a String guaranteed not to `==` the otherwise identical (`equal`) original.

Comment: @Carl, @Michael: To elaborate more on Jon Skeet's comment: using str.substring() returns a new string, referencing the same char array of str. If you don't need str anymore, then use new String(str.substring(..)). Otherwise you may be using much more memory than necessary.

Comment: @Jon: OK, I leave my answer as a proof that documentation isn't perfect :( BTW isn't it implementation detail? And where can I read about such "trims"?

Comment: @Carl: Calling that constructor *with a string literal* is mostly pointless, but it's definitely useful when it comes to other cases. In this case I hadn't read the javadoc - it doesn't just say "use of this constructor is unnecessary"... it says "*Unless an explicit copy of original is needed* use of this cosntructor is unnecessary" which is very different. That's fine. However, the *start* of the String javadoc talks about "equivalent" code where it's definitely *not* equivalent.

Comment: @Eyal, @Jon: You're correct, but that doesn't apply to the context of this question, because the original String is a literal (and thus assuredly not a substring of an existing string). @Jon: If the doc really mumbles about "equivalent" then it's indeed incorrect; I hadn't looked but just relied on the quote.

Comment: Response edited: I added first part of sentence with "use of this cosntructor is unnecessary".

Answer (score 2):

The following are some comparisons:

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello";
String s3 = new String("Hello");

System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //true

System.out.println(s1 == s3);   //false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); //true

s3 = s3.intern();
System.out.println(s1 == s3); //true
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); //true
```

When `intern()` is called the reference is changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle differences between String object and string literal.

```
String s = "abc"; // creates one String object and one reference variable
```

In this simple case, "*abc*" will go in the pool and *s* will refer to it.

```
String s = new String("abc"); // creates two objects,and one reference variable
```

In this case, because we used the `new` keyword, Java will create a new String object
in normal (non-pool) memory, and *s* will refer to it. In addition, the literal "*abc*" will
be placed in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

`String s = new String("FFFF")` creates 2 objects: `"FFFF"` string and `String` object, which point to `"FFFF"` string, so it is like pointer to pointer (reference to reference, I am not keen with terminology).

It is said you should never use `new String("FFFF")`

Comment: Not really. FFFF is already there created by the compiler. At runtime either zero or one object is created.

Comment: wrong , there is one object and one reference variable