# String Constant Pool memory sector and garbage collection

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I read this question on the site [How is the java memory pool divided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262328/1376167) and i was wondering to which of these sectors does the "String Constant Pool" belongs?

And also does the `String` literals in the pool ever get GCed?

The `intern()` method returns the base link of the `String` literal from the pool.

If the pool does gets GCed then wouldn't it be counter-productive to the idea of the string pool? New `String` literals would again be created nullifying the GC.

(It is assuming that only a specific set of literals exist in the pool, they never go obsolete and sooner or later they will be needed again)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399/what-type-of-memory-heap-or-stack-string-constant-pool-in-java-gets-stored

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know String literals end up in the "Perm Gen" part of non-Heap JVM memory. Perm Gen space is only examined during Full GC runs (not Partials).

In early JVM's (and I confess I had to look this up because I wasn't sure), String literals in the String Pool [never got](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html) GC'ed. In the newer JVM's, [WeakReferences](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interned.html) are used to reference the Strings in the pool, so interned Strings can actually get GC'ed, but only during Full Garbage collections.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the JavaDoc for String.intern() doesn't give hints to the implementation, but according to [this page](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interned.html), the interned strings are held by a weak reference. This means that if the GC detects that there are no references to the interned string except for the repository that holds interned strings then it is allowed to collect them. Of course this is transparent to external code so unless you are using weak references of your own you'll never know about the garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

**String pooling**

> String pooling (sometimes also called as string canonicalisation) is a
> process of replacing several String objects with equal value but
> different identity with a single shared String object. You can achieve
> this goal by keeping your own Map<String, String> (with possibly soft
> or weak references depending on your requirements) and using map
> values as canonicalised values. Or you can use String.intern() method
> which is provided to you by JDK.
>
> At times of Java 6 using String.intern() was forbidden by many
> standards due to a high possibility to get an OutOfMemoryException if
> pooling went out of control. Oracle Java 7 implementation of string
> pooling was changed considerably. You can look for details in
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6962931 and
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6962930.

**String.intern() in Java 6**

> In those good old days all interned strings were stored in the PermGen
> – the fixed size part of heap mainly used for storing loaded classes
> and string pool. Besides explicitly interned strings, PermGen string
> pool also contained all literal strings earlier used in your program
> (the important word here is used – if a class or method was never
> loaded/called, any constants defined in it will not be loaded).
>
> The biggest issue with such string pool in Java 6 was its location –
> the PermGen. PermGen has a fixed size and can not be expanded at
> runtime. You can set it using -XX:MaxPermSize=96m option. As far as I
> know, the default PermGen size varies between 32M and 96M depending on
> the platform. You can increase its size, but its size will still be
> fixed. Such limitation required very careful usage of String.intern –
> you’d better not intern any uncontrolled user input using this method.
> That’s why string pooling at times of Java 6 was mostly implemented in
> the manually managed maps.

**String.intern() in Java 7**

> Oracle engineers made an extremely important change to the string
> pooling logic in Java 7 – the string pool was relocated to the heap.
> It means that you are no longer limited by a separate fixed size
> memory area. All strings are now located in the heap, as most of other
> ordinary objects, which allows you to manage only the heap size while
> tuning your application. Technically, this alone could be a sufficient
> reason to reconsider using String.intern() in your Java 7 programs.
> But there are other reasons.

**String pool values are garbage collected**

> Yes, all strings in the JVM string pool are eligible for garbage
> collection if there are no references to them from your program roots.
> It applies to all discussed versions of Java. It means that if your
> interned string went out of scope and there are no other references to
> it – it will be garbage collected from the JVM string pool.
>
> Being eligible for garbage collection and residing in the heap, a JVM
> string pool seems to be a right place for all your strings, isn’t it?
> In theory it is true – non-used strings will be garbage collected from
> the pool, used strings will allow you to save memory in case then you
> get an equal string from the input. Seems to be a perfect memory
> saving strategy? Nearly so. You must know how the string pool is
> implemented before making any decisions.

[source.](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/)

Answer (score 0):

`String` literals don't get created into the pool at runtime. I don't know for sure if they get GC'd or not, but I suspect that they do not for two reasons:

- It would be immensely complex to detect in the general case when a literal will not be used anymore
- There is likely a static code segment where it is stored for performance. The rest of the data is likely built around it, where the boundaries are also static

Comment: `Strings don't get created into the pool at runtime`?? so are you saying `String`s are allocated memory at compile-time??

Comment: @WickeD: Sorry I mistyped, I meant "String literals".

Answer (score 0):

Strings, even though they are immutable, are still objects like any other in Java. Objects are created on the heap and Strings are no exception. So, `Strings that are part of the "String Literal Pool" still live on the heap, but they have references to them from the String Literal Pool.`

For more please refer this link

```
      `http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html`
```

Edited Newly :

```
public class ImmutableStrings

                {

                    public static void main(String[] args)

                   {
                        String one = "someString";
                        String two = new String("someString");

                        one = two = null;
                    }
                 }
```

Just before the main method ends, how many objects are available for garbage collection? 0? 1? 2?

The answer is 1. Unlike most objects, String literals always have a reference to them from the String Literal Pool. That means that they always have a reference to them and are, therefore, not eligible for garbage collection.

neither of our local variables, one or two, refer to our String object, there is still a reference to it from the String Literal Pool. Therefore, the object is not elgible for garbage collection.The object is always reachable through use of the intern() method

Comment: according to your link, even if no reference refers to the Strings on the heap they still have a reference from the pool. So they shouldn't be GCed, right??