# What is the difference between creating String as new() (inside heap not in string pool)and literal(inside string pool)?

Tags: java, string, heap-memory, string-pool

When we create string with new() Operator, it’s created in heap and not added into string pool while String created using literal are created in String pool itself which exists in PermGen area of heap. is it right ????????
Is my explanation correct.....

Comment: my question is about storage which is not duplicate..

Comment: answer to your question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399/what-type-of-memory-heap-or-stack-string-constant-pool-in-java-gets-stored