# What's the difference between a string and a literal?

Tags: java, computer-science

What is the type of "I like Comp Sci!"? I'm pretty sure its either a string or a literal, can anyone point out the difference between the two and help me find the answer

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal

Comment: The two terms aren't mutually exclusive (that is, something can be a "string literal").  Better check your textbook.

Comment: @mwan: That question is very specific to JavaScript.

Comment: @Gabe - It's actually very specific to Java, but point taken - the question lacks context.

Comment: @mwan: Oops, you're right; it's Java. The context of the question is just generic CompSci terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is a sequence of characters. A literal is data that's typed in as part of the program. If you have `"I like Comp Sci"` typed into your program, then it's a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, it would be considered both a string and a literal. A string is a collection of characters that make up a section of text. A literal is an unconditional constant which is directly entered into your source code. They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I disagree.  It's not a language specific concept.  A literal is represented by the actual string of characters, but a string is just a data type that can be represented by a reference name.  But, programmers definitely use the term "string" for both, but you would never say String myString; is a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a data type, but a string literal is when a string is defined *literally* usually in quotes:

```
String myString = "This is a literal string";
```

In the example String is the type, myString is a variable or reference name, and the text in quotes is a literal string.