# What's the difference between String s = "something"; and String s = new String("something");

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between string object and string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

When initializing a String object there are at least two ways, like such:

```
String s = "some string";
String s = new String("some string");
```

What's the difference?

Comment: See this: [difference between string object and string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3297867/977676

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Java language has special handling for strings; a string literal automatically becomes a `String` object.

So in the first case, you're initializing the reference `s` to that `String` object.

In the second case, you're creating a new `String` object, passing in a reference to the original `String` object as a constructor parameter.  In other words, you're creating a copy.  The reference `s` is then initialized to refer to that copy.

Answer (score 7):

In first case you can take this string from pool if it exist there.
In second case you explicitly create new string object.

You can check this by these lines:

```
String s1 = "blahblah";
String s2 = "blahblah";
String s3 = new String("blahblah");
String s4 = s3.intern();
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s1 == s3);
System.out.println(s2 == s3);
System.out.println(s1 == s4);

Output:
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: +1: You could add `String s4 = s3.intern(); System.out.println(s1 == s4);`

Comment: Sure, it will complete our example

Comment: thanks, you mentioned string pool. that's helpful, but I can only accept one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

String s = "some string";  assigns that value to s from string pool (perm.gen.space) (creates one if it does not exist)

String s = new String("some string"); creates a new string with value given in constructor, memory allocated in heap

The first method is recommended as it will help to reuse the literal from string pool

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, the first one assigns `"some string"` to `s`, while the second one assigns a copy of `"some string"` to `s` (since `"some string"` is already a `String`). I see no practical reasons to do this in 99.9% of cases, thus I would say that in most contexts, the only difference between the two lines is that:

1. The second line is longer.
2. The second line might consume more memory than the first one.
3. As @Anish-Dasappan mentions, the second one will have it's value in heap, whereas the first one will be in the string pool - I'm not sure this has any interest for the programmer, but I might be missing a clever trick there.