# String Primitive / String Class Difference?

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
String str = "stackoverflow";
```

&

```
String str = new String("stackoverflow");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between string object and string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It differs in how the string is taken from pool.

1.
When you say,

```
String str = "stackoverflow"
```

It will first check if `"stackoverflow"` already exists in String pool. If it does, then it will use the same from pool.

This is the reason why when,

```
String str1= "stackoverflow";
String str2 ="stackoverflow";

str1==str2? --> will be true
```

The result of above will be true, because same String object from pool is used.

2.
When you do,

```
String str = new String("stackoverflow");
```

Always, a new String object is created, irrespective of a same one already exists in pool or not.

So,

```
String str1= "stackoverflow";
String str2 =new String("stackoverflow");
String str3 =new String("stackoverflow");
```

Here, str2 and str3 will again create a new String object.

so, str2, str3 and str1 all refer to different objetcts and `str2!=str3!=str1`

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for the constructor `public String(String arg)` says:

> *Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, **the
>   newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an
>   explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is
>   unnecessary since Strings are immutable.***

When you do 
`String str = "stackoverflow"`
The compiler creates String object for you from the literal.

When you do:
`new String("stackoverflow");`
two are created, one by the compiler and one by you.

Answer (score 2):

Java has a pool for strings. More info : http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

Answer (score 2):

The first line allocates memory for the stackoverflow string. It then points the variable to this location.

The second line allocates space for the string. And then it creates a new String class. It copies the string from the first place to the new place in memory. Finally, it points the variable to that location.

All you do in the second example is create more work for the computer and use up more memory.

Comment: >>> `until the next garbage collection`: Actually, the literal won't get GCed, nor `str` if you use it when GC kicks in

Comment: ... because they(literas) are intern()ed