# Initializing a class object using literals

Tags: java, string, initialization

If I write this code :

```
String s = new String("TestString");
```

I understand how s refers to a string created dynamically. s is not an object in itself, but refers to one.

But I am not able to figure out what this means :

```
String s = "TestString";
```

Q1. If it would have been some primitive data type I would understand, but what does this signify for a class type ?

Q2. Is this kind of initialization allowed for user created classes as well ?

---

Java Level : Beginner

Comment: This has been answered in great depth here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3297877/1686330

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1. If it would have been some primitive data type I would understand, but what does this signify for a class type ?

In this case, `"TestString"` is a string literal. A string literal *also* serves as a reference to an instance of `String`. This is per the language specification, [§3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). So, in your particular case `"TestString"` is a reference to an instance of `String`, and you are assigning that same reference to your variable `s`.

Now, there are some rather special things about `String`s that are referred to by literals. Two string literals with the same value (logically, as strings) always refer to the same instance of `String`. This is due to the "[interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)" of string literals.

However, when you say

```
String s = new String("TestString");
```

it is still the case that `"TestString"` refers to an instance of `String`, in fact to an instance in the string intern pool, but it is *not* the case that `s` refers to this same string. Instead, `s` is initialized to have its value equal to `"TestString"`, but it is in fact a new reference. That is:

```
String s = new String("TestString");
String t = "TestString";
System.out.println(s == t);
```

This will print `false`.

> Q2. Is this kind of initialization allowed for user created classes as well ?

No.

Comment: Just to clarify, string literals are added to the string constants pool. That means that the same string, created multiple times using the literal double quote syntax, will refer to the same instance. In code, this means `"test" == "test"`, but `new String("test") != new String("test")`

Comment: The string constants pool is typically referred to as the string intern pool.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "TestString";
```

Is the normal way to create a String. In fact when you do:

```
String s = new String("TestString");
```

What you're doing is create a string first, then passing it as an argument to new String(); So the question is not why the first one exists, but why the second one does. The answer is pretty subtle and you probably won't ever care: The first way creates a String literal that doesn't get garbage collected, and is shared on all the VM. The second one, instead, does. This means, for performance reasons, there are cases when you want to use the second form, like when working with very very large strings.

You can read more about it here:

http://kjetilod.blogspot.com.es/2008/09/string-constructor-considered-useless.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

> The most direct way to create a string is to write:
>
> String greeting = "Hello world!";
>
> In this case, "Hello world!" is a string literal—a series of
>   characters in your code that is enclosed in double quotes. Whenever it
>   encounters a string literal in your code, the compiler creates a
>   String object with its value—in this case, Hello world!.
>
> As with any other object, you can create String objects by using the
>   new keyword and a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. If it would have been some primitive data type I would understand,
>   but what does this signify for a class type ?

No, this is special case, in case of String literals, `String s = "someString"` statement means we are referring to `someString` which is stored in string constant pool. `someString` will be an instance of `String` class but will be stored in string literal pool.

The special thing about String literal pool will be.

String s = "someString";
String s1 = "someString";

Here, `s == s1' will return`true` as they will refer to the same object in string literal pool.

String s2 = new String("someString");
String s3 = new String("someString");

Here, `s2 == s3` will return `false` as both string will be created in non-constant pool memory.

You can find a good tutorial regarding strings here

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/19/the-string-constant-pool/
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/string-immutability-in-java/

> Q2. Is this kind of initialization allowed for user created classes as
>   well ?

No we can't.