# Why people use new String instead of certain value?

Tags: java

**Simple code:**

```
class MyClass<T>
{

private T t;

    public void add(T t)
    {
       this.t = t;
    }

    public T get()
    {
     return t;   
    }  
}
```

And then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass<String> StringClass = new MyClass<>();

    StringClass.add("This is string");

 // **Or actually it can be:  StringClass.add(new String("This is string"));**
```

I saw that people use `StringClass.add(new String("This is string"))` instead of simple version `StringClass.add("This is string")`. What's the difference?

Same story with `Integers`.

Comment: Also note that java naming conventions states that variable names should start with a lowercase character.

Comment: But this code works in both versions. The result is the same. So what's the difference?

Comment: Read the duplicate question/answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between
`String foo = "bar"`

and

`String foo = new String("bar")`

is that the first one does not create a new `String` object but rather, it looks for that value in the existing `String` values that you have created. This is called interning the value. This saves memory.

The one with the `new` keyword assigns new memory for the String object you created.

```
public class StringInternExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String foo1 = "bar";
        String foo2 = "bar";

        String foo3 = new String("Hello, Kitty");
        String foo4 = new String("Hello, Kitty");

        if(foo1 == foo2){ // compare addresses. Same address = no new memory assigned
            System.out.println("No new memory has been assigned for foo2");
        }

        if(!(foo3 == foo4)){ // compare addresses. Different addresses = new memory
            System.out.println("New Memory has been assigned for foo4");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The main difference between these two methods is that the former tries to re-use an existing string from the string pool, whereas the latter explicitly creates a new one.

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: Definitely not the same.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and the SSCCE has loaded 100%.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal

Comment: Thanks! So the point is not to create new object of string.