# Confuse about creating the object

Tags: java, object

I am just starting out with Java. But I had a big puzzle when I am in the first chapter.
It says that we have to "initialize" the handle when we are creating one, like `String s = "asdf"`, and later it says we have create a new object for the string `s` again, `String s = new String("asdf");`.

I think the string `s` already has an object (asdf) in the "initialization", but why we still have to re-create it again(if I am understanding it right)?

Hope someone can explain this more to me, in book it is just skipped.

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal

Comment: Read this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java

Comment: Hi guys thanks. Both links worked out for my question!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str1 = "asdf";               //This is a String literal
String str1 = new String("asdf");   //This is a String object
```

String *objects* are on the *heap*, whereas the literals are on the *common pool* for string literals.

Noe that if you do `String s = "asdf";` and then `String s = new String("asdf");` you'll get a compilation error for redeclaring `s`.

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) for further information.

Comment: Alright. So a String _object_ needs to create a new space of the memory to str1, however a String _literal_ is like quoting (or linking?) an already-established memory space (not sure if I put it in this way right) to it?