# a Question regarding how exactly .distinct() works for an intStream

Tags: java

I have a String which I turn into an int stream of the ASCI numbers of the char values of each char of the String and then map it back to a String and also print out every char.

All of this works but I have a weird interaction with the .distinct() function that I don't quite understand.

It works just fine for my printer(c) function and the Output is:

```
hello d
hello c
hello b
hello a
```

so it doesn't print the second b but if I print out `a` itself after the String still has the 2nd b.

What is the reason for that interaction?

public class MapTesting {
public static void main(String [] args) {

```
      String a = "dcbba";
      a.chars().distinct().mapToObj( c -> (char) c).forEach(c -> MapTesting.printer(c));
      
      System.out.println(a);
      
  }
  public static void printer(Character c) {
      System.out.println("hello " + c);
  }

      }
```

Comment: Did you expect your function to modify the string in `a`?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example, including all code, input and output (as well as expected output), so we can see what is going on?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes that's more or less my question but I assume it just doesn't? Is there a different Method for that or would you have to use something like a StringBuilder?

Comment: @marstran public class MapTesting {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
String a = "dcbba";
   a.chars().distinct().mapToObj( c -> (char) c).forEach(c -> MapTesting.printer(c));
System.out.println(a);
   
 

  }
  public static void printer(Character c) {
   System.out.println("hello " + c);
  }

   }

Comment: Just edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stream` objects don't modify the original collection/object, they act on a copy. But more importantly, [Strings are always immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138587/what-is-difference-between-mutable-and-immutable-string-in-java), so `a` will have all the contents you've defined it with, yes.

`distinct()` creates a `Set` behind the scene, but is not really related to the question you seem to be asking

Comment: I was just wondering why distinct() influences the forEach part and not the String itself.
S distinct() just can't influence the String itself, correct?

Comment: You can think of the IntStream is added into a `Set<Integer>`, one element at a time, thereby removing duplicates, then the `set.stream()` gets returned