# How to compare strings in java?

Tags: java

== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.

I saw this post [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) . And I still don't get why you get false when you compare

// ... but they are not the same object
  `new String("test") == "test"`  // --> false

or

```
String str1 = new String("JAVA");
String str2 = new String("JAVA");
System.out.println(str1==str2);
```

Does this happen because they have different name or what is the reason ?

Comment: [whats the difference between `equals` and `==`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and), [Difference between string object and string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

Comment: `==` compares the memory (pointer) location of the objects where as `equals` is used to compare the quality of the physical contents of the object, so the two objects could have different memory locations, but are equal (based on the contract of their `equals`)

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the == operator compares memory addresses, not contents.

Note that String is an object, not a primitive, that is probably why people get confused, you can compare primitives with == and it will be fine, but with objects you want to compare their contents.

Answer (score -2):

Use equals.
   `str1.equals(str2);`

Comment: true, but still, the answer is quite sparse. Could you add some more details why it is better to use `equals` and why `==` doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry didn't fully read the question