# Counting duplicate values in Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hash map that looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> varX = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

And I can't for the life of me work out how to count the number of duplicate values. 
For example, If `put("001", "DM");` into the hash map and `put("010", "DM");` as well, how can count if there are two values int the ArrayList section of the Hashmap.

For example, the output would look something like this:

`DM:2` as I 'put' two DM values into the Hashmap.

Comment: You can't `put("001", "DM");`. `"DM"` is not an `ArrayList<String>`. What do you actually mean?

Comment: Are you fine with using a second HashMap to count?

Comment: You should definitly check [Guava Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap). It stores a `Collection` as the value, but you don't have to care about that. You can simply write `multiMap.put("DM", "123");`. And mind, that you should switch your *key* and *value*. `DM` should be the *key*.

Answer (score 2):

You have a HashMap that maps `String` to `ArrayList<String>`.

Doing `put("001", "DM")` on this map will not work as was pointed out to you in the comments by **@Sotirios Delimanolis**.

You would get an error that looks like:

```
The method put(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
```

Based on your example behavior, you want a `HashMap` that maps `String` to `String` (i.e. `put("001", "DM");`

Now, assuming you have that:

```
HashMap<String, String> varX = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And you want to count **how many keys map to the same value**, here's how you can do that:

```
varX.put("001", "DM");
varX.put("010", "DM");

// ...

int counter = 0;
String countingFor = "DM";
for(String key : varX.keySet()) {            // iterate through all the keys in this HashMap
    if(varX.get(key).equals(countingFor)) {  // if a key maps to the string you need, increment the counter
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(countingFor + ":" + counter);  // would print out "DM:2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap hm =new HashMap();
hm.put("01","one");
hm.put("02","two");
hm.put("03","one");
hm.put("04","one");
hm.put("05","two");
HashMap newHm = new  HashMap();
         Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                if(newHm.containsKey(pair.getValue())){
                    newHm.put(pair.getValue(), Integer.parseInt(newHm.get(pair.getValue()).toString())+1 );
                }else{
                    newHm.put(pair.getValue(),1 );
                }
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: Output:If you print your newHm you get "one"-3, "two"-2.

Answer (score 0):

As Sotirios says, you can only put an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Josh");
put("001", names);
```

If you want to insert Strings into the HashMap, define it as follow:

```
Map<String,String> example = new HashMap<String,String>();
example.put( "001", new String( "Rooney" ));
```

Regards,

Comment: why new String("Rooney")? what's wrong with "Rooney"?

Comment: Both can be used without problem: I like to create the object String, because in the HashMap it is defined as the String class.  And I prefer it, that's all :)

Comment: Using a string literal `"Rooney"` will also create a `String` object.  All you've done is create a wasted duplicate object.

Comment: You prefer to create duplicate String Objects? Mhh, ok. Its like prefer using raw types instead of generics.

Comment: @MartaFernandez, you might have some things confused, check out this link [String Object vs Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18635326/3928341)

Comment: I wasted? By using "new" Java is not responsible for creating the object as you would the other way. Remember that String is not a primitive data in java.

Comment: The difference between `new String("Test")` and `"Test"` is, that the first one will *always* create a new instance of `String`. The latter will create a new instance for the first call and [intern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning) that instance. If you call `"Test"` a second time, then you will get that instance, instead of a completely new one. Therefore, your system doesn't have to store several `String` instances containing the same value.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. I seen the link of Nem and I read the comment of Tom. Sorry for my confusion... x_x And thank you for the correction

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.frequency(map, "value");` is used to count the passed object in collection.
Following is the declaration of that method:

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```