# Is String a class or data type or both?

Tags: java, c#

When we use `String X="apple";` Now is `X` variable or object?
As we can use `X.Method` hence it should be object only but to define an object we should use:
`String X= new String ();`
But we did like `String X = "apple";`
So how come `X` is an  object or even if it is variable then how can we use variable.method?

Comment: Why do you think that "variable" and "object" are mutually exclusive concepts? *reference* variables refer to objects

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3297877/6462890

Comment: `X` is a reference to an instance of `String`; all strings are objects.

Comment: This is tagged java and C#. They handle strings a little bit different from one another. Just to keep in mind...

Comment: @UnholySheep: Variables and objects *are* different things. The *value* of a reference variable is a reference, but that doesn't mean that the words should be used interchangably. In this case, `X` is a variable, and its value is a reference to a string object.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172

Comment: @Fildor: Possibly more importantly, if "data type" in the title is meant to be "primitive", C# and Java handle value types *very* differently.

Comment: since java and C# handle these things differently you have to choose one or the other!

Comment: @JonSkeet ;) The "little" was a little "tongue-in-cheek" I admit.

Answer (score 2):

A Java String is simply a class - BUT as the JavaDoc documentation of String states: "..All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class..."

So the language literal "abc" is another way of saying String.create("abc") if there would be such a method. The compiler itself manages these literals.
So for example ("abc"=="abc") is true, but (new String("abc")==new String("abc")) is false.
That's why, in Java, you always need to use equality operator to test x.equals(y)

See also [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Comment: "So sometimes, with, x="abc";y="abc"; then x==y is true. But not always !!" No, that's *always* true, and guaranteed by the language specification.

Comment: You did Not answer my question in particular which is in body. When we use String X="apple"; Now is X variable or object? As we can use X.Method hence it should be object only but to define an object we should use: String X= new String (); But we did like String X = "apple"; So how come X is an object or even if it is variable then how can we use variable.method?

Comment: @raghuarora `X` would always be a variable.

Comment: Hi Jon, makes sense. I was unprecise in my first answer. See edits: ("abc"=="abc") is true, but (new String("abc")==new String("abc")) is false.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense.

Comment: @raghuarora: I think you're using the terms "variable" and "object" incorrectly to start with. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172.

Answer (score 1):

Although C# and Java are quite different in how they handle the `String`, the answers your questions in the two languages are quite similar.

> Now is X variable or object?

`X` is technically a variable *storing* a *reference* to a `String` object. The string object it references is the string `"apple"`.

> So how come X is an object or even if it is variable then how can we use variable.method?

Whether something is an object or not does not depend on how you create it. *Yes*, you could create a string using `new String(...)`, that will be an object as well. The difference between using a string *literal* and calling the string constructor is that using a string literal will get the string from the string pool, instead of creating a brand new string.

Whether or not you are able to use `variable.method` does not depend on whether it is an object or not. The concept of "object" is really specified by the language spec.

In C#, instances of reference types are objects, so `string` (a reference type) instances are objects too. In Java, class instances and arrays are objects. `String` is a class, so instances of it, like `"apple"`, are objects.

If you want to see the definition of "object" in each language, here are some places you can look for them.

- JLS section 4.3.1
- C# Language Specification Section 1.3

Comment: "X is technically a variable storing a String object." No, I'd say it's a variable storing a *reference* to a String object. It doesn't store the object itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oops! Fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

`X` is a variable. In Java and C# the `String` type is a reference type, so `X` is a variable *that is a reference*. At the end of that reference is an *object* of type `String` with the contents `"apple"`. When we do `X.Method`, this means "dereference the variable `X` to get to an object, and invoke the `Method` method on the object".

This is how all reference-types work.

> but to define an object we should use: String X= new String ();

No, that's a *familiar way* of instantiating objects, but there is additional compiler syntax to make this more convenient when using `String`s, and possibly to add "interning" so that you don't allocate more `String` objects than necessary. In C#. for example, `string x = "apple";` will become something like (in MSIL):

```
ldstr "apple"
stloc.0
```

where the `ldstr` is a special IL instruction for loading constants with automated interning. If we were creating a `String` based on a byte buffer rather than a compile-time constant, there are *different constructors* for `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different questions and lacks in your question:

1. As stated by other person, there is a difference how String is
   handled in Java vs C#.
2. Another point is that you are asking if String is an object or a
   variable, but these two are not mutually exclusive. Objects are
   variables but they are instances of user defined types i.e. classes
   or structures, where a variable in general can also be of built in
   types like `int`, `float`...
3. In C# Built-in Types can have methods, too. So this is not a
   property to distinguish between built-in types and user-defined
   types.
4. `string` is built-in type which is an alias for the predefined type `System.String`. But `string` is not a simple type like `int`, `float`. For more info, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table)
5. `String X = "apple";` is compiled in a special way in C#: There is
   an IL Instruction which allows in C# to assign a literal to an
   object reference(here `X`). This IL instruction is Ldstr which
   pushes a new object reference to a string literal stored in
   metadata. For more info:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx

Comment: "Objects are variables" - no they're not. I suggest you read stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have read your answer in the thread, but it is not correct in my view. A Variable is a storage location paired with an associated symbolic name (an identifier) (Wikipedia). As soon as you create a variable the compiler allocates memory on the stack for the variable regarding the variable type.

Comment: @JonSkeet An object in general is an instance of class. As soon as you create an object (calling the constructor with new Classname()), the compiler allocates memory for the object regarding the class and your reference can access the object memory. So Objects are accessed like variables with complex internal structure(wikipedia).

Comment: Just because you can use the referenced object doesn't mean there's a variable. Consider: `int x = new Object().hashCode();`. The *only* variable in that statement is `x`, and that's not the same as the object that's created. Objects and variables are clearly related, but they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet In C# you just see one variable for this code. But if you look the msil or the assembly you will see that x is not the only variable here. On MSIL first the newobj will be called which creates the object on the stack and returns a reference to it. After that ldfld will be called. Thus, by calling newobj you are creating an object on the stack which is the same operation you do for a variable. I haven't said object and variable are the same. Every object is a variable. But every variable is not an object. object=>variable.

Comment: But we're not talking about the assembly or the IL. We're talking about the Java and C# languages. Not that your claim is correct anyway - it won't use `ldfld`, because there's no field involved. And having just tried the equivalent C# code, in non-debug release mode, you just end up with `newobj` and `callvirt` calls. But no, fundamentally an object is *not* a variable. They are different, and you're confusing things by claiming every object is a variable. That doesn't match the description in either the C# or Java language specifications.

Comment: For exactly your code it may use callvirt, because you are calling the method hasCode(). I tried it for a field. But this is not the point, but the newobj command that is called, which creates an object on the stack. But if you still think that object and variables are different and my statement is incorrect, then show me a reference claiming that. Because I can show you also other articles of other developers confirming exactly my statement.

Comment: "I tried it for a field." Well yes, if you store the value in a field, then there's a variable, because fields are variables. And no, the new object isn't created on the stack. The object is on the heap (as an implementation detail); the reference is on the stack. My references are the C# language specification and the Java language specification. I consider those pretty definitive - whereas there are all kinds of "articles" claiming all kinds of bogus things. (The "Java passes arguments by reference for classes" myth still exists, for example.)

Comment: From the start of the C# 5 language spec: "Variables represent storage locations. Every variable has a type that determines what values can be stored in the variable. C# is a type-safe language, and the C# compiler guarantees that values stored in variables are always of the appropriate type. The value of a variable can be changed through assignment or through use of the ++ and operators." None of that holds for objects.

Comment: At this point, I'm running out of patience and time. If you can find references *in the Java language specification or C# language specification" that define object to be a variable, please do. Otherwise I'll continue to assume that I already know what I'm talking about.

Comment: For Java, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1. You would think that if objects were variables, it would be mentioned...

Answer (score -1):

First of all it depends upon platform to platform , but you can say it's a wrapper around native string, or a class that represents string .

Comment: It's hard to know whether or not if agree with this until you define "native string".

Comment: @JonSkeet native string I mean the underlying string representation for example c string .

Comment: Then I disagree completely, for both Java and C#. (Well, depending on the meaning of your "or", but there's basically no point in mentioning native strings here.)