# Why do these two cases show different results for Array elements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reference, primitive

Here, the value of Array arr elements do not change after changing values of a and b.

```
int a=10, b=20;
int[] arr = {a,b};
a = 20;
b = 10;
System.out.println("a = " + a); // a=20
System.out.println("b = " + b); // b=10
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // prints [10, 20]
```

Here, intArr2 elements change value once you change value of IntArr elements.

```
int[] intArr = {10,12};
int[] intArr2 = intArr;
intArr[1] = 1000;
System.out.println("intArr2[1]: " + intArr2[1]); // prints 1000
```

And here, it doesn't change the value of str Array elements:

```
        String word1="abc";
        String word2="def";
        String[] str = {word1, word2};
        word1 = str[1];
        word2 = str[0];
        System.out.println("word1 = " + word1); //def
        System.out.println("word2 = " + word2); //abc
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str)); // prints [abc, def]
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: in the first case, you define the array based upon the values of a and b. But their correlation ends there.

Comment: See also: [Is Java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/3419894). Once you understand that concept (and realise that arrays are *always* objects, never primitives) you should be in a good place to be able to answer this question for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case, values of `a & b` are assigned to array `arr`. So after assigned any change in `a, b` doesn't reflect to `arr`.

In second case `intArr2` is using the reference of `intArr`, so any change in any one of these array should reflect both, in fact the location is unique.

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Then, what about in this case:

Comment: @Seth If you read through the question I linked you should be able to arrive at the answer to both questions yourself

Comment: As JonK said, you can see this one as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal

Answer (score -1):

Every object, has 2 things that can make it be distinguished.

- Its Value
- Its address

one is having a value(intArr) and the other is having address (intArr2)