# What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?

Tags: java, identity, equality, object-comparison

I wanted to clarify if I understand this correctly:

- `==` is a reference comparison, i.e. both objects point to the same memory location
- `.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects

Comment: yeah, pretty much

Comment: Yes, spot on. You can think of `.equals()` as *meaningfully equivalent*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: A sentence like "both objects point to the same memory location" is sloppy language, which can make understanding more difficult. You mean: "both variables refer to the same object". Note that a variable is not an object; a variable is a *reference* to an object. Objects don't "point to" anything.

Comment: In C# (and many other languages) the *equality operator* ( **==** ) corresponds to the `Object.Equals()` method. Descendants classes, like `String`, can define what it means for two strings to be **==** by overriding the `.Equals` method. Java cannot do that. The Java `String` class (and no class in Java) has a way to override **==** to make it behave the way it should behave. This means you **must** call `.equals()` yourself manually.

Comment: "==" is for Primitive Types and ".equals()" is to compare Reference types(If "==" is used on reference types, the hash code is compared by default)

Answer (score 740, accepted):

In general, the answer to  your question is "yes", but...

- `.equals(...)` will only compare what it is written to compare, no more, no less.
- If a class does not override the equals method, then it defaults to the `equals(Object o)` method of the closest parent class that has overridden this method.
- If no parent classes have provided an override, then it defaults to the method from the ultimate parent class, Object, and so you're left with the `Object#equals(Object o)` method. Per the Object API this is the same as `==`; that is, it returns true *if and only if* both variables refer to the same object, if their references are one and the same. Thus you will be testing  for **object equality** and not **functional equality**.
- Always remember to override `hashCode` if you override `equals` so as not to "break the contract". As per the API, the result returned from the `hashCode()` method for two objects **must** be the same if their `equals` methods show that they are equivalent. The converse is *not* necessarily true.

Comment: if `==` checks for memory reference then why am I getting this strange behavior in [this][1][1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ducE-yZEDyyjoKUTkTEsw3sdSw740d0Z5iiJz3IzABE/edit?usp=sharing       I expected output to be true. can clear my confusions

Comment: @JSK print the values of d1 and d2 and I think you'll see why you're returning false.

Comment: @BoDidely I figured it out. It was because all the wrapper classes are immutable.

Comment: `The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).`
<br/>
`Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.`
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 137):

With respect to the String class:

The equals() **method** compares the "value" inside String instances (on the heap) irrespective if the two object references refer to the same String instance or not. If any two object references of type String refer to the same String instance then great! If the two object references refer to two different String instances .. it doesn't make a difference. Its the "value" (that is: the contents of the character array) inside each String instance that is being compared.

On the other hand, the "==" **operator** compares the value of **two object references** to see whether they refer to the same **String instance**. If the value of both object references "refer to" the same String instance then the result of the boolean expression would be "true"..duh. If, on the other hand, the value of both object references "refer to" **different String instances** (even though both String instances have identical "values", that is, the contents of the character arrays of each String instance are the same) the result of the boolean expression would be "false".

As with any explanation, let it sink in.

I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: so for strings == is reference equals aswell? ie works the same as for other objects?

Comment: (Thread necromancy, I know...) For `String`s, `==` is reference equals as well, yes, but it _usually_ works (as in two `String`s with the same content will _usually_ be `==` to each other), because of how Java handles `String`s.  It won't always, and it's certainly bad practice, but it's a common mistake, particularly from people coming from other languages.

Comment: To add on to Tonio's comment. `String` build from string literal will be added to something called the `String constant pool`, e.g. `String s1 = "someString"; String s2 = "someString;"` both `s1` & `s2` will share the same reference.  `s1 == s2` will return true. But if they were constructed via the `String constructor`, e.g. `String s1 = new String("someString"); String s2 = new String("someString");` then they will not share the same reference. `s1 == s2` will return false.

Answer (score 75):

There are some small differences depending whether you are talking about "primitives" or "Object Types"; the same can be said if you are talking about "static" or "non-static" members; you can also mix all the above...

Here is an example (you can run it):

```
public final class MyEqualityTest
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        String s1 = new String( "Test" );
        String s2 = new String( "Test" );

        System.out.println( "\n1 - PRIMITIVES ");
        System.out.println( s1 == s2 ); // false
        System.out.println( s1.equals( s2 )); // true

        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();

        System.out.println( "\n2 - OBJECT TYPES / STATIC VARIABLE" );
        System.out.println( a1 == a2 ); // false
        System.out.println( a1.s == a2.s ); // true
        System.out.println( a1.s.equals( a2.s ) ); // true

        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();

        System.out.println( "\n3 - OBJECT TYPES / NON-STATIC VARIABLE" );
        System.out.println( b1 == b2 ); // false
        System.out.println( b1.getS() == b2.getS() ); // false
        System.out.println( b1.getS().equals( b2.getS() ) ); // true
    }
}

final class A
{
    // static
    public static String s;
    A()
    {
        this.s = new String( "aTest" );
    }
}

final class B
{
    private String s;
    B()
    {
        this.s = new String( "aTest" );
    }

    public String getS()
    {
        return s;
    }

}
```

You can compare the explanations for "==" (Equality Operator) and ".equals(...)" (method in the java.lang.Object class) through these links:

- ==: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html
- .equals(...): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Interesting example. Different perspective from the above answers. Thanks!

Comment: Best answer in my opinion, as it's clearer than the other full-text answers without losing the explanation (if you undertand class and static concepts, of course)

Answer (score 54):

The difference between `==` and `equals` confused me for sometime until I decided to have a closer look at it.
Many of them say that for comparing string you should use `equals` and not `==`. Hope in this answer I will be able to say the difference.

The best way to answer this question will be by asking a few questions to yourself. so let's start:

**What is the output for the below program:**

```
String mango = "mango";
String mango2 = "mango";
System.out.println(mango != mango2);
System.out.println(mango == mango2);
```

if you say,

```
false
true
```

I will say you are *right* but **why did you say that**?
and If you say the output is,

```
true
false
```

I will say you are *wrong* but I will still ask you, why you think that is right?

Ok, Let's try to answer this one:

**What is the output for the below program:**

```
String mango = "mango";
String mango3 = new String("mango");
System.out.println(mango != mango3);
System.out.println(mango == mango3);
```

Now If you say,

```
false
true
```

I will say you are *wrong* but **why is it wrong now**?
the correct output for this program is

```
true
false
```

Please compare the above program and try to think about it.

Ok. Now this might help (please read this : [print the address of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396927/how-to-print-the-address-of-an-object-if-you-have-redefined-tostring-method) - not possible but still we can use it.)

```
String mango = "mango";
String mango2 = "mango";
String mango3 = new String("mango");
System.out.println(mango != mango2);
System.out.println(mango == mango2);
System.out.println(mango3 != mango2);
System.out.println(mango3 == mango2);
// mango2 = "mang";
System.out.println(mango+" "+ mango2);
System.out.println(mango != mango2);
System.out.println(mango == mango2);
 
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(mango));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(mango2));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(mango3));
```

can you just try to think about the output of the last three lines in the code above:
for me ideone printed this out ([you can check the code here](https://ideone.com/JA6NgB)):

```
false
true
true
false
mango mango
false
true
17225372
17225372
5433634
```

Oh! Now you see the **identityHashCode(mango) is equal to identityHashCode(mango2) But it is not equal to identityHashCode(mango3)**

Even though all the string variables - mango, mango2 and mango3 - have the **same** value, which is "mango", `identityHashCode()` is still not the same for all.

Now try to uncomment this line `// mango2 = "mang";` and run it again this time you will see all three `identityHashCode()` are different.
Hmm that is a helpful hint

we know that if `hashcode(x)=N` and `hashcode(y)=N` => `x is equal to y`

I am not sure how java works internally but I assume this is what happened when I said:

```
mango = "mango";
```

java created a string `"mango"` which was pointed(referenced) by the variable `mango` something like this

```
mango ----> "mango"
```

Now in the next line when I said:

```
mango2 = "mango";
```

It actually reused the same string `"mango"` which looks something like this

```
mango ----> "mango" <---- mango2
```

Both mango and mango2 pointing to the same reference
Now when I said

```
mango3 = new String("mango")
```

It actually created a completely new reference(string) for "mango". which looks something like this,

```
mango -----> "mango" <------ mango2

mango3 ------> "mango"
```

and that's why when I put out the values for `mango == mango2`, it put out `true`. and when I put out the value for `mango3 == mango2`, it put out `false` (even when the values were the same).

and when you uncommented the line `// mango2 = "mang";`
It actually created a string "mang" which turned our graph like this:

```
mango ---->"mango"
mango2 ----> "mang"
mango3 -----> "mango"
```

This is why the identityHashCode is not the same for all.

Hope this helps you guys.
Actually, I wanted to generate a test case where `==` fails and `equals()` pass.
Please feel free to comment and let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: Does the `mango == mango2` happen because you didn't create `mango2 `as a new String object, and instead just directly referenced `"mango"`?

Comment: wrong example to use String to clear doubts on == and equals, String when not used with new are put into String Pool and whenever same string is assigned to new reference it points to same string in pool. So probably use some custom object example for == and .equals() comparison.

Answer (score 35):

> The **==** operator tests whether two variables have the **same references
> (aka pointer to a memory address)**.

```
String foo = new String("abc");
String bar = new String("abc");

if(foo==bar)
// False (objects are identical but not same)

bar = foo;

if(foo==bar)
// True (Now, objects are identical and same)
```

> Whereas the **equals()** method tests whether two variables refer to objects
> that have the **same state (values)**.

```
String foo = new String("abc");
String bar = new String("abc");

if(foo.equals(bar))
// True (The objects are identical but not same)
```

Comment: Wrong.  if(foo==bar) this should be true not false. It will reused the same string "adc". Test it in a sandbox, it will return true for both.

Comment: Your answer is only valid for String objects and because String overrides equals to return true if the "represents the same sequence of characters".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

For the general case of the original question, your answer is either wrong, misleading, or incorrect

Answer (score 15):

You will have to override the equals function (along with others) to use this with custom classes.

The equals method compares the objects.

The `==` binary operator compares memory addresses.

Answer (score 14):

`==` is an *operator* and `equals()` is a *method*.

Operators are generally used for *primitive* type comparisons and thus `==` is used for memory address comparison and `equals()` method is used for comparing *objects*.

Comment: Simple and easiest answer

Answer (score 9):

```
 String w1 ="Sarat";
 String w2 ="Sarat";
 String w3 = new String("Sarat");

 System.out.println(w1.hashCode());   //3254818
 System.out.println(w2.hashCode());   //3254818
 System.out.println(w3.hashCode());   //3254818

 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(w1)); //prints 705927765
 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(w2)); //prints 705927765
 System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(w3)); //prints 366712642


 if(w1==w2)   //  (705927765==705927765)
 {
   System.out.println("true");
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("false");
 }
 //prints true

 if(w2==w3)   //  (705927765==366712642)
 {
   System.out.println("true");
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("false");
 }
 //prints false


 if(w2.equals(w3))   //  (Content of 705927765== Content of 366712642)
 {
   System.out.println("true");
 }
 else
 {
   System.out.println("false");
 }
 //prints true
```

Comment: Simple and best explanation

Answer (score 8):

Both == and .equals() refers to the same object if you don't override .equals().

Its your wish  what you want to do once you override .equals(). You can compare the invoking object's state with the passed in object's state or you can just call super.equals()

Answer (score 6):

*Here is a general thumb of rule for the difference between **`relational operator ==`** and **`the method .equals()`**.*

`object1 == object2` compares if the objects referenced by object1 and object2 refer to t**he same memory location in Heap**.

`object1.equals(object2)` compares **the values of object1 and object2 regardless of where they are located in memory**.

This can be demonstrated well using String

**Scenario 1**

```
 public class Conditionals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str1 = "Hello";
       String str2 = new String("Hello");
       System.out.println("is str1 == str2 ? " + (str1 == str2 ));
       System.out.println("is str1.equals(str2) ? " + (str1.equals(str2 )));
    }

 }



The result is
      is str1 == str2 ? false
      is str1.equals(str2) ? true
```

**Scenario 2**

```
public class Conditionals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str1 = "Hello";
       String str2 = "Hello";
       System.out.println("is str1 == str2 ? " + (str1 == str2 ));
       System.out.println("is str1.equals(str2) ? " + (str1.equals(str2 )));
    }

}

The result is 
  is str1 == str2 ? true
  is str1.equals(str2) ? true
```

This string comparison could be used as a basis for comparing other types of object.

For instance if I have **a Person class**, I need to define the **criteria base on which I will compare  two persons**. Let's say this person class has **instance variables of height and weight.**

So creating person objects `person1 and person2` and for comparing these two using the `.equals()` I need to override the **equals method of the person class** to define based on which instance variables(heigh or weight) the comparison will be.

However, the `== operator will still return results based on the memory location of the two objects(person1 and person2)`.

For ease of generalizing this person object comparison, I have created the following test class. **Experimenting on these concepts will reveal tons of facts**.

```
package com.tadtab.CS5044;

public class Person {

private double height;
private double weight;

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(height);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
/**
 * This method uses the height as a means of comparing person objects.
 * NOTE: weight is not part of the comparison criteria
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(height) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.height))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.setHeight(5.50);
    person1.setWeight(140.00);
    
    Person person2 = new Person();
    person2.setHeight(5.70);
    person2.setWeight(160.00);
    
    Person person3 = new Person();
    person3 = person2;
    
    Person person4 = new Person();
    person4.setHeight(5.70);
    
    Person person5 = new Person();
    person5.setWeight(160.00);
    
    System.out.println("is person1 == person2 ? " + (person1 == person2)); // false;
    System.out.println("is person2 == person3 ? " + (person2 == person3)); // true 
    //this is because perosn3 and person to refer to the one person object in memory. They are aliases;
    System.out.println("is person2.equals(person3) ? " + (person2.equals(person3))); // true;
    
    System.out.println("is person2.equals(person4) ? " + (person2.equals(person4))); // true;
    
    // even if the person2 and person5 have the same weight, they are not equal.
    // it is because their height is different
    System.out.println("is person2.equals(person4) ? " + (person2.equals(person5))); // false;
}

}
```

Result of this class execution is:

```
is person1 == person2 ? false
is person2 == person3 ? true
is person2.equals(person3) ? true
is person2.equals(person4) ? true
is person2.equals(person4) ? false
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remember that `.equals(...)` has to be implemented by the class you are trying to compare. Otherwise, there isn't much of a point; the version of the method for the Object class does the same thing as the comparison operation: [Object#equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

The only time you really want to use the comparison operator for objects is wen you are comparing Enums. This is because there is only one instance of an Enum value at a time. For instance, given the enum

```
enum FooEnum {A, B, C}
```

You will never have more than one instance of `A` at a time, and the same for `B` and `C`. This means that you can actually write a method like so:

```
public boolean compareFoos(FooEnum x, FooEnum y)
{
    return (x == y);
}
```

And you will have no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

When you evaluate the code, it is very clear that (==) compares according to memory address, while equals(Object o)  compares hashCode() of the instances. 
That's why it is said do not break the contract between equals() and  hashCode() if you do not face surprises later.

```
    String s1 = new String("Ali");
    String s2 = new String("Veli");
    String s3 = new String("Ali");

    System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
    System.out.println(s3.hashCode());


    System.out.println("(s1==s2):" + (s1 == s2));
    System.out.println("(s1==s3):" + (s1 == s3));


    System.out.println("s1.equals(s2):" + (s1.equals(s2)));
    System.out.println("s1.equal(s3):" + (s1.equals(s3)));


    /*Output 
    96670     
    3615852
    96670
    (s1==s2):false
    (s1==s3):false
    s1.equals(s2):false
    s1.equal(s3):true
    */
```

Answer (score 4):

The major difference between == and equals() is

1) == is used to compare primitives.

For example :

```
        String string1 = "Ravi";
        String string2 = "Ravi";
        String string3 = new String("Ravi");
        String string4 = new String("Prakash");

        System.out.println(string1 == string2); // true because same reference in string pool
        System.out.println(string1 == string3); // false
```

2) equals() is used to compare objects.
For example :

```
        System.out.println(string1.equals(string2)); // true equals() comparison of values in the objects
        System.out.println(string1.equals(string3)); // true
        System.out.println(string1.equals(string4)); // false
```

Answer (score 4):

Example 1 -

Both == and .equals methods are there for reference comparison only. It means whether both objects are referring to same object or not.

[Object class equals method implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l149)

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
       Object ob1 = new Object();
       Object ob2 = ob1;
       System.out.println(ob1 == ob2); // true
       System.out.println(ob1.equals(ob2)); // true
     }    
}
```

[image]

Example 2 -

But if we wants to compare objects content using equals method then class has to override object's class equals() method and provide implementation for content comparison. Here, String class has overrided equals method for content comparison. All wrapper classes have overrided equals method for content comparison.

[String class equals method implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l974)

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
       String ob1 = new String("Hi");
       String ob2 = new String("Hi");
       System.out.println(ob1 == ob2); // false (Both references are referring two different objects)
       System.out.println(ob1.equals(ob2)); // true
     }
}
```

[image]

Example 3 -

In case of String, there is one more usecase. Here when we assign any string to  String reference then string constant is created inside **String constant pool**. If we assign same string to new String reference then no new string constant is created rather it will refer to existing string constant.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
       String ob1 = "Hi";
       String ob2 = "Hi";
       System.out.println(ob1 == ob2); // true
       System.out.println(ob1.equals(ob2)); // true
     }
}
```

[image]

Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

[Java API equals() method contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 3):

Also note that `.equals()` normally contains `==` for testing as this is the first thing you would wish to test for if you wanted to test if two objects are equal.

And `==` actually does look at values for primitive types, for objects it checks the reference.

Answer (score 3):

== operator always reference is compared. But in case of

> equals() method

it's depends's on implementation if we are overridden equals method than it compares object on basic of implementation given in overridden method.

```
 class A
 {
   int id;
   String str;

     public A(int id,String str)
     {
       this.id=id;
       this.str=str;
     }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
      A obj=new A(101,"sam");
      A obj1=new A(101,"sam");

      obj.equals(obj1)//fasle
      obj==obj1 // fasle
    }
 }
```

in above code both obj and obj1 object contains same data but reference is not same so equals return false and == also.
but if we overridden equals method than

```
 class A
 {
   int id;
   String str;

     public A(int id,String str)
     {
       this.id=id;
       this.str=str;
     }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
       A a1=(A)obj;
      return this.id==a1.id;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
      A obj=new A(101,"sam");
      A obj1=new A(101,"sam");

      obj.equals(obj1)//true
      obj==obj1 // fasle
    }
 }
```

know check out it will return true and false for same case only we overridden

> equals method .

it compare object on basic of content(id) of object

> but ==

still compare references of object.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth adding that for wrapper objects for primitive types - i.e. Int, Long, Double - == will return true if the two values are equal.

```
Long a = 10L;
Long b = 10L;

if (a == b) {
    System.out.println("Wrapped primitives behave like values");
}
```

To contrast, putting the above two Longs into two separate ArrayLists, equals sees them as the same, but == doesn't.

```
ArrayList<Long> c = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Long> d = new ArrayList<>();

c.add(a);
d.add(b);
if (c == d) System.out.println("No way!");
if (c.equals(d)) System.out.println("Yes, this is true.");
```

Comment: Wrapper objects for primitive types - i.e. Integer, Long, Double == may not return true even if the two values are equal. It purely depends on Wrapper's cache. 

Below code will print false because default cache is limited to -128 to 127.
                `Long a = 128l;
  Long b = 128l;
  System.out.println(a == b);`

Answer (score 2):

`==` can be used in many object types but you can use `Object.equals` for any type , especially Strings and Google Map Markers.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class StringPool {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Cat";// will create reference in string pool of heap memory
    String s2 = "Cat";
    String s3 = new String("Cat");//will create a object in heap memory

    // Using == will give us true because same reference in string pool

    if (s1 == s2) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }

    // Using == with reference and Object will give us False

    if (s1 == s3) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }

    // Using .equals method which refers to value

    if (s1.equals(s3)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }

    }
  }
```

----Output-----
   true
   false
   true

Answer (score 1):

Since Java doesn’t support operator overloading, `==` behaves identical
for every object but `equals()` is method, which can be overridden in
Java and logic to compare objects can be changed based upon business
rules.

Main difference between `==` and equals in Java is that `"=="` is used to
compare primitives while `equals()` method is recommended to check
equality of objects.

**String comparison is a common scenario of using both `==` and `equals()` method.** Since java.lang.String class override equals method, It
return true if two String object contains same content but `==` will
only return true if two references are pointing to same object.

**Here is an example** of comparing two Strings in Java for equality using `==` and `equals()` method which will clear some doubts:

```
 public class TEstT{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    String text1 = new String("apple");
    String text2 = new String("apple");
          
    //since two strings are different object result should be false
    boolean result = text1 == text2;
    System.out.println("Comparing two strings with == operator: " + result);
          
    //since strings contains same content , equals() should return true
    result = text1.equals(text2);
    System.out.println("Comparing two Strings with same content using equals method: " + result);
          
    text2 = text1;
    //since both text2 and text1d reference variable are pointing to same object
    //"==" should return true
    result = (text1 == text2);
    System.out.println("Comparing two reference pointing to same String with == operator: " + result);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The [String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings) (aka [interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning)) and [Integer pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877086/why-do-comparisons-with-integer-valueofstring-give-different-results-for-12)** blur the difference further, and may allow you to use `==` for objects in some cases instead of `.equals`

This can give you greater performance (?), at the cost of greater complexity.

E.g.:

```
assert "ab" == "a" + "b";

Integer i = 1;
Integer j = i;
assert i == j;
```

Complexity tradeoff: the following may surprise you:

```
assert new String("a") != new String("a");

Integer i = 128;
Integer j = 128;
assert i != j;
```

I advise you to stay away from such micro-optimization, and *always* use `.equals` for objects, and `==` for primitives:

```
assert (new String("a")).equals(new String("a"));

Integer i = 128;
Integer j = 128;
assert i.equals(j);
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is "Yes".

In Java, the `==` operator compares the two objects to see if they point to the same memory location; while the `.equals()` method actually compares the two objects to see if they have the same object value.

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference between *identity* and *equivalence*.

`a == b` means that a and b are *identical*, that is, they are symbols for very same object in memory.

`a.equals( b )` means that they are *equivalent*, that they are symbols for objects that in some sense have the same value -- although those objects may occupy different places in memory.

Note that with equivalence, the question of how to evaluate and compare objects comes into play -- complex objects may be regarded as equivalent for practical purposes even though some of their contents differ.  With identity, there is no such question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `==` compares if two objects have the same reference on the heap, so unless two references are linked to the same object, this comparison will be false.

`equals()` is a method inherited from **`Object`** class. This method by default compares if two objects have the same referece. It means:

`object1.equals(object2)` **<=>** `object1 == object2`

However, if you want to establish equality between two objects of the same class you should override this method. It is also very important to override the method `hashCode()` if you have overriden `equals()`.

Implement `hashCode()` when establishing equality is part of the Java Object Contract. If you are working with collections, and you haven't implemented `hashCode()`, Strange Bad Things could happen:

```
HashMap<Cat, String> cats = new HashMap<>();
Cat cat = new Cat("molly");
cats.put(cat, "This is a cool cat");
System.out.println(cats.get(new Cat("molly"));
```

`null` will be printed after executing the previous code if you haven't implemented `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, `==` checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas `.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

Answer (score 0):

equals() method mainly compares the original content of the object.

If we Write

```
    String s1 = "Samim";
    String s2 = "Samim";
    String s3 = new String("Samim");
    String s4 = new String("Samim");

    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    System.out.println(s2.equals(s3));
    System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
```

The output will be

```
true 
true 
true
```

Because equals() method compare the content of the object.
in first System.out.println() the content of s1 and s2 is same that's why it print true.
And it is same for others two System.out.println() is true.

Again ,

```
    String s1 = "Samim";
    String s2 = "Samim";
    String s3 = new String("Samim");
    String s4 = new String("Samim");
    
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    System.out.println(s2 == s3);
    System.out.println(s3 == s4);
```

The output will be

```
true
false 
false
```

Because == operator mainly compare the references of the object not the value.
In first System.out.println(), the references of s1 and s2 is same thats why it returns true.

In second System.out.println(), s3 object is created , thats why another reference of s3 will create , and the references of s2 and s3 will difference, for this reason it return "false".

Third System.out.println(), follow the rules of second System.out.println(), that's why it will return "false".

Answer (score 0):

In Java, == and the equals method are used for different purposes when comparing objects. Here's a brief explanation of the difference between them along with examples:

== Operator:
The == operator is used for reference comparison. It checks whether two references point to the exact same object in memory.

Example:

```
String str1 = new String("Hello");
String str2 = new String("Hello");
String str3 = str1;

System.out.println(str1 == str2); // false (different objects)
System.out.println(str1 == str3); // true (same object)
```

In the example, str1 and str2 are different objects with the same content, but == returns false because it checks for reference equality. str3 points to the same object as str1, so str1 == str3 returns true.

equals Method:
The equals method is used for content or value comparison. It is meant to be overridden in custom classes to provide a meaningful comparison based on the object's contents.

Example:

```
String str1 = new String("Hello");
String str2 = new String("Hello");

System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); // true (content-based comparison)
```

In this example, equals is overridden in the String class to compare the content of the strings. Therefore, str1.equals(str2) returns true because the content of the strings is the same.