# String Creation in Java (Memory Usage)

Tags: java, string

In Java, is there a difference between the following two pieces of code? I'm looking for answers in terms of memory usage and the String pool.

The first:

```
String s = new String();

s = "abcdef";
```

The second:

```
String s = new String("abcdef");
```

Thanks.

Comment: in the first case you create two strings (one empty) and second "abc...". In the second just one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool?rq=1 among others contain a lot of information regarding this. If there's something from all the various questions and answers on SO that you don't understand, a specific question would be more useful.

Comment: And the first comment here is completely incorrect. Both cases create two `String` objects. String literals are interned and stored in the string pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a creation and a value assignment in the first one. In the second one you just do a creation. You make (nearly) twice processor activities in the first one. Speaking of memory, there's no difference.

And String pool explanation to your question:

[What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool?rq=1)

Comment: why there is no difference in memory? you create two in fact two string objects in the first case.

Comment: @gregory561 - and you create two in the second case ;) That literal doesn't magically go away - it goes in the string pool.