# Java source code -- value assignments for class types

Tags: java, string, jvm, variable-assignment

I am looking to see in the Java source code what happens 
when a variable is declared & assigned a value.

I haven't been able to spot this in **java.lang.Class**.

Particularly, looking to see what happens in

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
```

**String** is immutable and thus by the outcome of **"s1 == s2"**, these two references-- **s1** and **s2** are pointing to 
the same object and when

```
String s2 = "abc";
```

is issued, Java is spotting the location of the object 
**"abc"** that already is created and **s1** is referring to, and assigning this location 
to **s2** (?)

I am looking to see how this is handled behind the scenes in Java.

//===========================================

EDIT:

The Q here is-- **how Java is handling this in its source code.**

The [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool) is answering this **in part**. I'm looking to see this all in the **source code**-- if it's not one of those native.

I know this a naive Q, but didn't expect these responses.

Comment: A `String` being immutable has *nothing* to do with the internal String pool java uses for string literals.

Comment: If `String`s weren't immutable, they couldn't be interned.

Comment: @chrylis Yes but just because something *is* immutable doesn't mean it's interned. Java could have had an immutable String without interning. In fact, that's exactly what you get with `new String()`

Comment: Sure they could. It would be a terrible idea, because it would lead to hard-to-track bugs (and security holes); but it'd be perfectly possible to have a rule of "two string constants of the same string will always return the same mutable `String` object."

Comment: @BrianRoach Oh, absolutely you could, but it's the fact that `String`s are immutable that make interning possible... er (@yshavit), practical.

Comment: (In fact, if you don't have a security manager that prevents reflection-based modifcation, `Strings` [aren't even immutable](https://gist.github.com/yshavit/6143346).)

Comment: @Roam, re `if it's not one of those native` -- the String interning is done by the JVM during class loading, so yes, it's native. The closest you'll see of it is in the source is the declaration for `java.lang.String.intern()`, but that's just a native function (at least in openjdk): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.intern%28%29

Comment: @yshavit I was looking to see which constructor of String / how invoked upon an assignment that would/not involve pooling. that's "how the compiler is behaving"-- before handing it over to String. or handing it over right away upon on assignment of a Class type value and leaving the rest to String-in-this-case. Havent had a thorough look but nothing showing in java.lang.Class.

Comment: @Roam you are better off using `javap` if you want a look at the bytecode for a class to get an idea of how string literals/constants work. I think my answer addresses you concern.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the JVM. Implementations may vary.

Answer (score 0):

One mental model:

1. At compile time, all [String literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) are written into the bytecode of the class definition in a "[constants table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)". String instances in particular will be stored into the interned string pool (during loading?).
2. At runtime, when a string literal is to be referenced, it is retrieved with a `ldc` load from the constants table which is an interned string object.

In your example...

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
```

May become something like:

```
String s1 = ldc #1
String s2 = ldc #1
```

Where:

```
constant #1 = "abc".intern();
```

> I haven't been able to spot this in java.lang.Class.

I'm not sure why you would be looking at `java.lang.Class`, if anywhere, I would be looking at the `ClassLoader`, however even class loading is `native`. If you want to see some sort of "code", you can examine the bytecode of a compiled class with `javap`. There is an [old guide](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200408/ScjpTipLine-javap.html) that somewhat explains reading bytecode instructions. You'll notice that all references to String literals are `ldc` instructions which is for loading constants.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to see this all in the source code-- if it's not one of those native.

It's about as native as a thing can get -- it's handled by the JVM, which has a bytecode operation for "load this string literal".

Take this code:

```
public class StringLiterals {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello, world";
  }
}
```

If you compile that and then run `javap -c StringLiterals`, you'll get this:

```
Compiled from "StringLiterals.java"
public class StringLiterals extends java.lang.Object{
public StringLiterals();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String hello, world
   2:   astore_1
   3:   return

}
```

The second code `0` and `1` are what correspond to `String s = "hello, world"`; the code `0` corresponds to the string literal `"hello, world"`. It says to load const #2 in the `.class` file, and hints that it's the string literal `hello, world`. If you run `javap -c -verbose StringLiterals` you'll see all of the consts defined in the `.class` file, and it'll confirm that the second one is that string literal:

```
Compiled from "StringLiterals.java"
public class StringLiterals extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "StringLiterals.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method   #4.#13; //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = String   #14;    //  hello, world
const #3 = class    #15;    //  StringLiterals
...
```

The JVM is free to handle this however it wants, but openjdk does it natively, so you won't see any of the relevant code in the Java source.