# While Loops User Input

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm having trouble with a while loop in a Java program. I want to have a loop that has endless input until a certain input is reached, as an example if you run the program it would look like this
"Enter a letter" (user enters b) "Your current input is B" "Enter another letter" (user enters c) "Your current input is BC"

My loop:

```
while (myLock.open() == false) {

    System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");

    String inputString = myScan.nextLine();
    char inputTwo = inputString.charAt(0);
    String inputStringKeeper = inputStringKeeper + inputTwo;

    inputTwo = ' ';
    System.out.println(myLock.setValue(inputStringKeeper) + " your current combo is " + inputStringKeeper);
}
```

just FYI the myLock method is a method that unlocks a "padlock" when a certain input is reached and will say either "unlocked" or "still locked"
Sorry for the jumbled post, so hard to explain over text. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't link to pastebin, paste the code here. If the pastebin link goes down permanently, no one will be able to see the linked resource anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the declaration of `inputStringKeeper` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the scope of the variables you define. In this case, `inputStringKeeper` lives as long as the current iteration, meaning that future iterations will have their own `inputStringKeeper` (since you create a new one every time).

If you want to have a common variable for all the particular steps of that `while`'s iteration, define it outside of the block and use it inside.

---

Unrelated, but I might as well point some things out. Rather than using `myLock.open() == false`, use the unary (logical) operator *not* (`!`):

```
while(!myLock.isOpen())
```

It does the same, but it's easier to read.

Second, this is a good scenario to use a `StringBuilder` to avoid creating and storing a new `String` in the pool each time you concatenate a value.

```
StringBuilder inputStringKeeper = new StringBuilder();
```

Then, use the `append` function. This will handle the concatenation for you. Finally use the good'ol `toString` to get the `String` from the builder.

---

Some notions you might be interested into:

- [StringBuilder class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [A good answer about the String Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool)
- [An intro to the concept of Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)
- [Java Operators Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: I played around with apend and it is super useful, I can see myself using it a lot in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @user2957372 You're welcome. Just remember the way we roll here: [upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).