# Restore last fragment opened before close app

Tags: java, android

i have a problem. I want to restore last fragment opened before close my application and i would like to use SharedPreferences so i put into the onCreateView of each fragment a snippet of code that save a string to shared preferences and in the Main Activity i've this

```
if(savedIstanceState == null) {
            pref = new SharedPref(this);
            String prefe = pref.getPreString("LastPage");

            if(prefe == "0") {
                fragment = new Fragment0();
            } else if(prefe == "1") {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            } else if(prefe == "2") {
                fragment = new Fragment2();
            } else {
                fragment = new Fragment3();
            }

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        }
```

But return always Fragment3 also if in the preferences there are for example 0. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, dont compare Strings using `==`, use `equals`  instead. Secondly I assume you are saving correctly your preferences as you did not show how you store the value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which is the difference between == and equals? to save string data i have this method editor.putString(key, value).commit();

Comment: When you use ==, you are comparing if both objects are exactly the same (the same instance), using `equals` you are comparing the content (the string itself). This is not 100% true , but your comparison may return false using == even if both Strings have the same value. Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool