# Every time I use String, does it create a new String object?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Let's say that I need to iteratively retrieve a value of the same key from a Java hashmap.

```
  for(int i=0; i<INTEGER.MAX; i++)   
          map.get("KEY");
```

In this case, is the "KEY" string created every time I call map.get("KEY")? I was wondering if it's always better to have a String constant, or it doesn't matter.

Comment: String interning; it *is* a constant.

Comment: damn, i missed this.  easy points!! -)

Comment: Strings are constants and once created are being stored in so called  "string pool". You can read more about it here: [Java String Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool). But some may quarrel that it's a good practice to extract the commonly used string to a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. String constants are interned automatically, so any identical string literals all reference the same object in memory.

Some more information on this: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

An example of this:

```
String s1 = "Test";
String s2 = "Test";
String s3 = new String("Test");
s1 == s2;//Evaluates to true, because they are the same object (both created with string literals)
s1 == s3;//Evaluates to false, because they are different objects containing identical data
```

Comment: i don't think s3 interned automatically.

Comment: No. The String literal used in the constructor will be, but the final Object assigned to s3 won't be unless you explicitly intern it.

Comment: Then you should correct your answer also. These are not interned automatically.

Comment: @Vipin But s3 is being created with the Object constructor, which I never say is being interned automatically. Only String literals are.

Comment: Actually when u say "No" very first word I assume answer to the question is always No. And "String constant" comes just after No so I was referring it with all String objects (prepared by any way).

Answer (score 2):

Yes/No Answer depends on how you create String Objects. Below are the four scenarios I can think of as of now.

**Yes Cases**

1. **new String()** always creates new Object. It is not internedn(Doesn't go to String pool) so you
   can not take it back from memory.
2. **Concatenation ( "a" + "b" )** always creates new String Object and it is not interned (Doesn't go to String pool).

**No Cases**

3. **String a ="aa";** if already available it retrieves from the pool, when not available it creates a new object which is interned also (Goes to String pool as well)
4. **new String().intern() or "aa".intern()**; if already available it retrieves from pool , when not available it creates new object which
   is interned also (Goes to String pool as well).

Answer (score 1):

> is the "KEY" string created every time I call map.get("KEY")?

No.

[Java Strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm) are immutable, which allows the Java compiler to use a single instance for all string literals.
That is: **all identical string literals in your program will reference a single string object.**

In the rare cases you need identical strings to be wrapped in two separate objects, you must explicitly 
instantiate a String object:

```
String s1 = "bla";
String s2 = "bla";
// s1 == s2 
String s3 = new String ("bla");
// s1 != s3
```