# Why does == return true for a String comparison?

Tags: java, string

I have previously asked a question about comparing 2 strings and was told that I should always use .equals.

However, I do not understand why this then works:

```
 String y= "Mary";
 String x= "Mary";
 System.out.print(x==y);
```

This will print true, and I do not understand why.

Comment: Because `y` and `x` are both pointing to the same object in the *String constant pool*.

Comment: It's an implementation detail of the compiler and the JVM.

Comment: *"It's an implementation detail of the compiler and the JVM"* - Actually, it is required by the Java specification.  It is NOT just an implementation detail.

Comment: A bit more detail on the string pool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool

Comment: This is *why* you should always use .equals

Answer (score 3):

Because those two String(s) have the same reference identity, and that is because they came from the [String intern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) pool. If you were to add a `new String()` to one of them, like so -

```
String y= "Mary";
String x= new String("Mary");
System.out.print(x==y);
```

You would get `false`.