# Using '==' with strings? (Java)

Tags: java, string, equals, equality, sign

```
String str1 = new String("I love programming");
String str2 = new String("I love programming");
boolean boo = str1 == str2; // evaluates to false

String str1 = "I love programming";
String str2 = "I love programming";
boolean boo = str1 == str2; // evaluates to true
```

Why does first one evaluate to false and second one evaluate to true?

And here you can find more: [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool)

Comment: The compiler likely optimized away the second string and put them into the same object. Since strings are immutable there's no harm in doing so. The first two strings had their constructors called explicitly, so new objects were created, likely their internal pointer is also pointing to the same place where the last two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`==` will return true if the objects themselves have the same addresses. For space and efficiency reasons, repeated literals are optimized to use the same address. The second `str1` and `str2` are equal to the same address, thus `==` returns true.

In the first example, because you are explicitly declaring memory using the `new` keyword, the `str1` and `str2` don't have the same addresses. Thus, `str1==str2` evaluates to `false`.

When testing equality, use the `String.equals();` function instead. Thus, `str1.equals(str2); //true`

Comment: @Tyler: does that mean Java actually searches through its memory for equal Strings when declaring a new one? So when declaring `str2` it finds that `str1` is equal to it and thus sets it to the same address?

Comment: @dokaspar look up the docs for the `String.intern();` function. I'm not entirely sure about how each JDK implements interning exactly, but it should be something like that. Remember, only literals are interned, not new Objects.

Comment: @dokaspar I think it's implementation dependent what strings are really "same", but in this case it's done by the compiler: it sees the string four times (twice in the constructor calls), and stores them once in the constant pool of the class file. So there is no lookup at runtime, the classfile references the same string (constant, not object) several times. Exercise for the reader: are equal string literals in different class files the same?

Comment: (okay, so I tested it... at least on OpenJDK 7, they seem to be the same. I'd say the class loader matches the class file's constant pool against the interned strings)

Answer (score 1):

The equals() method compares the contents of the String and the == compares the reference in Java.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't answer the question. He didn't use compare method

Comment: well was just pointing out the difference between equals and == because his question is quite confusing

Answer (score 1):

It's there in the Java Memory Model

The first equality statement returns false as your're comparing two different references of two different objects as you used the key word `new` which allocate memory space inside the heap in to two distinct memory addresses, the seconds, the JVM will allocate memory space once "into the stack" (**from Java 7 they are in the heap as well**) and the compiler optimizes memory usage by making the two variables pointing to the same memory space which it explains that the equality result is `true`.

Here's an interesting reading about heap, stack, ...etc. [JVM Internals Blog](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html)

Cheers

Comment: This answer is not quite correct: String literals are required by the Java Language Specification to be interned, which means they can not be allocated on the stack.

Comment: your comment is right starting from java 7, thank's

Comment: Actually, it's been that way since Java 1.0, see for instance http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/3.doc.html#101083

Answer (score 0):

Not like C. (==) compares references of java string  variables. It compares two address where the strings are stored. Two compare them by values, you need to use string1.equals(string2).