# Memory Leaks occur in a local variable?

Tags: java, memory

This is an example code:

```
public void doSomething(){
   long currentTime = 1430668777967;
   System.out.println("Time: "+currentTime);
}
```

If I made the code above run multiple times would it be using more ram at the currentTime variable even after I stop using it and create a new one?

Note: I know I can just get it from `System`

Comment: GC will take care of `currentTime`. There is noway you are getting memory leak from `dosomething`.

Comment: I would recommend changing the title of this post, it's a bit misleading and not descriptive of the question.

Comment: Why this question is so downvoted? It is a beginner question, yes, but a legit question nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In fact `currentTime` is disposed of (freed) after `doSoemthing()` finishes because it is a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

the memory is allocated on the stack when currenttime is set.  then in the next line the string "Time: " and String representation of the long are concatinated to create a new string that is printed. the constructed temporary strings are released by the end of the method and the long is returned to the stack as the method exits.

Comment: *"the Strings are released by the end of the method"* Wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Comment: Its likely only the "Time: " string object would have been added to the pool. correct?  the other items would have been released.  they are not automatically intern-ed.

Comment: That's right sir, but that's the only string there :)

Comment: What about the constructed string that is passed to the println function? it will wind up getting a ref to the concatenated string also I would assume before the concatenation occurred the compiler created a temp string for the long? all these temp objects would be freed and not intern-ed.  Just thinking the downvote I got was overly harsh response.

Comment: Yes, there's a String constructed from the long. Still your answer explicitly states that the string "Time: " is released, which is wrong.

Comment: I'll edit it to add "temporary" strings to the answer.   I see how it could be interpreted to refer to the "time: " string (literal string).  in my mind I consider that a constant that is 'always around' (inter-ed or inlined, etc).