# What is wrong in using charAt function in this context?

Tags: java, string

I was trying to copy a word using this manner. I am not sure,I was following right manner handling `String`.

The code is:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String str="Hello";
      int i=0;
      String copy = "";
      while (str.charAt(i) !='\0')
      {
          copy = copy + str.charAt(i);
          i++;
      }

      System.out.println(copy);
   }
```

Running this code results in `Exception`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at ReverseWord.main(ReverseWord.java:15)
```

Am I using `charAt()` and checking null in right way? Or,I have wrong conception about `String` handling in `Java`?

Comment: You have a wrong conception about String handling. They're not 0 terminated. `String.length()` gives you the size.

Comment: In addition string concattenation in the way you do it used to be rather expensive, don't know if it has been changed in later Java releases.

Comment: Why would you want to copy a string? Try this `String str2 = new String(str);`. And read about string pooling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Answer (score 4):

You are using `String`s in the wrong way (for `Java`!) lets clarify some basic points to use String's in Java:

- **`String` are immutable**. This means each time you modify it `JVM` will create a new object. That is a lot of resources, so, in order of better programming you shouldn't use concatenation in `String`s, to make concatenation use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).
- **`Strings` does not end with any special symbol**, this could happen in some filetypes but not at `Strings` objects, so you have to get size with `length()` and use it to iterate if necessary.
- Always **take a loop at the API of any Java object** to know its functionallities: 
  [`StringAPI7`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) 
  [`StringAPI8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- To loop a `String` char by char you can do it with `for`, `while` and several more ways (splitting, converting...):

For loop example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

While example:

```
while (i < str.length()) {
```

Said that... Take a look at this code working **and** using what is explained:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello";
    int i = 0;
    // string builder is a mutable string! :)
    StringBuilder copy = new StringBuilder();
    // we iterate from i=0 to length of the string (in this case 4)
    while (i < str.length()) {
        // same than copy = copy + str.charAt(i)
        // but not creating each time a new String object
        copy.append(str.charAt(i));
        // goto next char
        i++;
    }

    // print result 
    System.out.println(copy);
}
```

**UPDATE**

> thanks... but while I am trying this to find a reverse did not get result

If what you want is to reverse the `String` (your code didn't do that, you must write `copy = str.charAt(i) + copy;`) is much easier with `StringBuilder`. Take a look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello";
    StringBuilder copy = new StringBuilder(str);
    copy.reverse();
    System.out.println(copy);
}
```

Comment: check my update... your code did't reverse the `String`... but in my update you will find the new code to reverse the `String`

Answer (score 1):

**FIrst way:**

Use the below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    copy = copy+str.charAt(i);
}
```

**Second Way:**

Convert `String` into `char[]`. then convert it back to `String`.

```
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
String copy = new String(ch);
System.out.println(copy);
```

Comment: I want to make OP to understand .. we can do it this with multiple ways.

Comment: for me `for` loops are more understandable, but a lot of people think same about `while` so I guess OP feels more comfy with `while` loops...