# What's wrong with new String?

Tags: java

I just failed a code review without any reason given due to my writing, for a function where `s` (of type String) is passed as a parameter

```
if (s == null){
    s = new String();
}
```

Said I should use `s = "";` instead. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Comment: Your question is unclear.. `s = new String();` doesn't compile. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: U wot? It does in Java 7.

Comment: [There's definitely a default `String` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String()), and it creates an empty `String`.

Comment: Adding to Bathsheba answer, Readability would improve if you make it `s = ""`.That might be one of the reason.

Comment: @Keerthivasan it's not readability. the first comments provided link and the given answer is correct.

Comment: @P45Imminent using `s = "" ` would save a little processing time as it will check in string pool, if the empty string exists it will refer there else it will make a new empty string. However that little processing time is not noticeable and there are chances that `""` empty string won't exist in string pool. so you can argue with reviewer.

Comment: Even better would be using a constant. Constants.EMPTY_STRING which = "", More importantly I would be checking the calling algorithm as to why on hell it would pass you a null string and fix it there. This type of null checking is inherently horrible.

Comment: I'm implementing an interface that has as a requirement that the parameter can be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always clarify with the reviewer?

`new String();` *always* creates a new string. (Isn't the Java syntax self-explantory?)

`s = ""`; will set the reference to an *interned* string and is therefore preferred.

Answer (score 4):

There is a preference in the `String` class when initialized with literals over initialization with the `new` keyword, this is because of the **JVM** optimizations, and because the **JVM** allocates strings initialized with literals directly in the `StringPool`.

Comment: but what if `""` is not available in String Pool?

Answer (score 3):

Both `s = new String();s = "";` expressions give a string object but there is a clear difference between the two. `s=new String()` will create a new object in the heap memory whereas if we create object using string literal `s = "";` it may return an existing object from String pool(**a cache of string objects**) if it already exists.

Example will make it more clear:

```
String a= "banana";
String b= "banana";
```

Here both a and b refer to the same object and hence `a==b` is true

```
String a =new String("banana")
String b= new String("banana")
```

Here both a and b refer to two different objects and hence `a==b` is false

Comment: how will `a==b` in the first example return true?

Comment: You seem to have made a mistake in the example: `a == b` in the first example will not return true, since "banana" will _never_ equal "orange". If both were "banana", _then_ they'd be equal.

Answer (score 1):

JVM handle it differently if you call:

- s = new String(); //The constructor will create new object everytime
  it's called
- s = ""; //The string literal will refer to the same    object in the
  common pool

You can find the full answer in the link bebow:
http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/19529/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder-tutorial

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "apple";
    String str2 = "apple";

    if(str1 == str2) {
        System.out.println("str1, str2: same object");
    } else {
        System.out.println("str1, str2: different object");
    }

    String str3 = new String("apple");
    String str4 = new String("apple");

    if(str3 == str4) {
        System.out.println("str3, str4: same object");
    } else {
        System.out.println("str3, str4: different object");
    }       
}
```