# What is difference between 2 string literals

Tags: java

I have one String literal which refers to a string pool reference

```
String s1 = "abc";
```

Suppose i create/assign a new String literal like:

```
String s2 = s1 + "pqr";
```

Which of the following will happen?

1. change contain of existing string pool object.
2. create new object in string pool and assign to `s2`, if yes then what is the size of `s2`;

Comment: The value assigned to `s2` is not in the string pool, unless you declare `s1` to be `final`.

Comment: And "change contain of existing string pool object." will definitely not happen, ever. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Deepest and most comprehensive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29978564/14637

Comment: The correct answer is 'neither'.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the referred question. That was about creating a String within and outside of String literal pool. This is about creating a String within the String Literal pool and then create an another from this String.

Comment: Any one can tell me what is the memory allocation of 'S2'.

Comment: I think this would be useful for you:
http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3

Comment: @Gabu `s2` is allocated in the heap.

Comment: @Igorovics So it is a duplicate of another of the 10,000 questions here on the topic.