# How to test a spring bean with prototype scope?

Tags: java, spring

I have a configuration class and a test class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SimpleConfiguration.class)
public class SimpleTest {
    @Autowired
    private String hello;

    @Autowired
    private String another;

    @Test
    public void should_not_same() {
        Assert.assertNotSame(hello, another);
    }
}
```

According to the definition of `prototype scope`, the `hello` and `another` object should be not same, but this test failed. Why? Thanks!

Comment: For your experiment you picked about the only type that's not suitable for a Spring Bean: a String. Also, why are you trying to test Spring Framework code?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Java are pooled for effeciency. You can read more about it here: [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)

So, even though Spring will call your `hello()` method multiple times to try to create a new object (since you want prototype scope), the JVM will return the same String instance anyway.

If you would do the following, the test should be ok:

```
public String hello() {
    return new String("hello");
}
```

Note that is is bad practise to create a String like this, but for the purpose of your test, this is how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like same String is being reused to construct both `hello` and `another` from String pool.

If you create a class, say `Person`, and do the same test it is passing the test.