# Regarding "+" operator and its StringBuilder implementation

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

From what I understand, the String concatenation "+" operator in Java is implemented using Stringbuilder, such that something like :

```
String s = "foo" + "bar"
```

internally compiles as :

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("foo").append("bar").toString();
```

So I tried something like this :

```
String foo1 = "foobar";
String foo2  = new String("foobar");
String foo3 = "foo" + "bar"; 
char[] fooarray = {'f','o','o','b','a','r'};
String foo4 = new String(fooarray);
```

Next I tested these against each other using == operator. The results were mostly what I expected : foo2 and foo4 did not return "==" for any other String.

However , foo3 == foo1 returns true. What is the reason for this ? The StringBuilder class's toString method internall calls "new String" , so shouldn't foo3 be a unique object, just like foo2 ?

Comment: String concatenation of two string *literals* are done by the *compiler*, not at runtime. So writing `"foo" + "bar"` is the same as writing `"foobar"`. It allows you to split a string literal over multiple lines, without performance penalty.

Comment: Also, if your Strings are `final`, then even, `String s = s1 + s2` will happen at compile time if `s1` and `s2` are references to String literals

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `foo3 == foo1` returns true is because of String pooling.

When you concatenate string literals (even `final` strings that aren't literals) the concatenation happens at compile time, so when the program executes the values `String foo1 = "foobar";` and `String foo3 = "foobar";`.

String pool or String table is a special area on the heap which stores String references.

Now, when you create String `foo1` it is kept in the pool if there is no other string literal with value `foobar`. But in case of `foo3` there is already a string literal with value `foobar` so `foo1` and `foo3` points to same object in the String pool, this is done to save memory.

When you create a String with new keyword the object resides on the heap but outside of String pool.

If you want a string created with new keyword to be in the String pool if same value already exists in the pool then you have to call String `intern()` method and assign back the reference to the String variable.

For more information - [What is the Java string pool and how is “s” different from new String(“s”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)