# What is the term used for reusing strings and colors?

Tags: java, android

When I have multiple colors, strings and drawables that are constantly reused throughout the whole application, what is the term for this to describe it?

Is this called inheritance?

Comment: Are you referring to java string pool? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be called

> constants

Since their value is unchanging. These would typically be `public static final` fields.

Inheritance is completely different, and you can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: So are they nothing to do with object orientation considering they're reused?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with regards to why reuse would make them related to object orientation.

Constants certainly aren't only used in object-orientated languages - you'll find them used in almost all languages