# Java - reference equality in strings

Tags: java, string, reference, equality

I'm preparing for the OCA and I am puzzled by reference equality in strings.
So given Case 1:

```
String s = "Hello";
if("Hello" == s){
    System.out.println("TRUE");//prints TRUE
}else {
     System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

But in Case 2:

```
String s = "";
s += "Hello";
if("Hello" == s){
    System.out.println("TRUE");
}else{
     System.out.println("FALSE"); //prints FALSE
}
```

I know that strings are immutable, but "==" checks for reference equality, and in the second case "s" is a reference that initially points to an empty string and then points to "Hello". So, why does the second case return false?
What am I missing?

Regarding:
[What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)
In my question, in both cases "s" is a string literal and found in the string pool. The above mentioned questions is about a string literal and a String object (which gets memory allocated).

Regarding:
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
My question asks "why", not "how".

[@Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel)
Yes I understand that ""+"Hello" is a different string than "", but we are discussing reference equality where "s" is a reference which first points to a string "", and then the same reference "s" points to another string "Hello". In both cases, before the if-clause, the reference "s" points to "Hello", but the results to the if-clause are different.

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: `"" + "Hello"` creates a new string.

Comment: i think you found a compiler opimization ;-)

Comment: ["The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28)."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) It's not a constant expression, because `s` isn't final (nor can it be, because you're using `s += ...`).

Comment: Well, (for anyone who lands on this page) after some further "digging" it turns out @Mark Rotteveel answer is correct. In Java, concatenation creates a new String object which gets memory allocated in the heap. Basically when the compiler sees a concatenation it internally creates that new String object.