# Query regarding String Pool

Tags: java

Suppose I have strings:

```
String a = "hello"; 
String b = "h";
String c = "ello";

String d = b+c;
```

When I check for `a==d` it returns false.

Please correct me if am wrong, the bytecode would contain string **d** value as **hello** right? I want to know why is it that during execution of the program,string d is not picked up from string pool as **hello** is already available in string pool and hence returning false as above when checked for equality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)

Comment: Declare b and c final, and it would be true.

Comment: @FilipRistic Can you tell me why its duplicate?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes true that. Can you kindly let me know why is that.

Comment: Because 3rd answer gives answer to your question.

Comment: @Anuraag because they are then compile-time constant expressions, so `b+c` is a compile-time constant expression, so it is evaluated to `"hello"` at compile time, and only one `"hello"` is inserted into the constant pool.

Comment: @AndyTurner this should be an answer. Current answers don't really cut it.

Comment: @FilipRistic No it does not explain the concept

Comment: @JBNizet answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please correct me if am wrong, the bytecode would contain string d value as hello right?

You are wrong. (You can see that you are wrong by inspecting the bytecode for yourself.)

The value of `d` is evaluated at runtime, by concatenating `b` and `c`.

It is only if you declare both `b` and `c` as `final` that this becomes true: then they are both compile time constant expressions (*).

This means that the value assigned to `d` is a compile-time constant expression, so it is evaluated at compile time to be `"hello"`. But only one `"hello"` is inserted into the constant pool, because no more are necessary.

Hence, `a == d` would be true.

---

(*) final-ness is a necessary but not sufficient condition to be a compile-time constant; the other relevant fact is that they are assigned a compile-time constant value, namely a string literal value.

Comment: Thank you.. Is StringBuilder also involved in this as mentioned in the 1st answer by noobsaibot

Comment: @Anuraag it isn't necessarily involved; it could be `d = "".concat(b).concat(c)`, or any other means (the implementation of concatenation by `+` is not stipulated by the language spec).

Comment: @Anuraag you can discover that by compiling your class, and then using `javap -c fully.qualified.name.of.YourClass`

Comment: @JBNizet that only tells you [the colour of one side of one sheep](http://www.mathmos.net/misc/jokes.html) ;) (in other words' it would only tell OP what his/her current compiler does to that code).

Comment: @AndyTurner sure, but that's the side you care about :)

Comment: @JBNizet I just tried the javap functionality and found that StringBuilder is involved.

Answer (score 2):

During the execution StringBuilder will be created which itself will create a String object out of char array.

Sample:
`StringBuilder dBuilder = new StringBuilder();
dBuilder.append(b);
dBuilder.append(c);
String d = dBuilder.toString();` // here new String(value, 0, count); will be called,
where value is the char array and count is the size of the resulting string.

Comment: Hi do you have any source for this information? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, assuming you have class Test.
Run `$ javac Test`  to compile then `$ javap -c Test.class` to disassemble.
Sample: https://pastebin.com/Fbbu9uCz

Comment: There is a note in the JLS that compiler may perform such kind of optimization.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Answer (score 0):

The **==** operator checks  two strings are point exactly the same object. here a,b,c Reference variable have  different hash Code.  actually **==** comparing the memory address. If they are both equal it will return true and false

Answer (score 0):

If you say to Java put the `d` value to the pool

```
String d = (b+c).intern();
```

it will return `true`; the example in here(https://ideone.com/Y100H4)