# String#intern() in jdk8

Tags: java, string, junit

Why these two similar code snippets lead to different results?

```
public class Test {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test1() {
        String s3 = "1" + new String("1");
        String s5 = s3.intern();
        System.out.println(s5 == s3);
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test2() {
        String s3 = "g" + new String("g");
        String s5 = s3.intern();
        System.out.println(s5 == s3);
    }
}
```

Tried in jdk 1.8.0_144 environment, got these answer (maybe different in jdk6):

> false
>    and
>    true

The first snippet should be true in Java8.
But more confusingly, If I moved the code into main method, It will result in true.

```
public class TestWithoutJunit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s3 = "1" + new String("1");
        String s5 = s3.intern();
        System.out.println(s5 == s3);
    }
}
```

I assume this is kind of JUnit optimizing, so I check bytecode, two code snippet inside jUnit and main function remain exactly same.

By the way, my Java version

> java version "1.8.0_144"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @AndréStannek Not if you understand the question.

Comment: Maybe gg is already interned somewhere else

Comment: @jontro `"gg"` is already interned by the fact that it is a string literal. JLS requires it. I strongly suspect a typo in the first method.

Comment: anyways you would need to look at the IR code. The first line could be optimized

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)`.

Comment: ran these snippets on jdk10, got all `true`s (as it should be)

Comment: @Stylex you should accept one of answer by using that checkmark next to voting arrows - do this for your old questions too ;) As seems that you never accepted any answer in your questions.

Comment: If I move all code snippet from JUnit to `public static void main(String[] args)`, two result will be all true.

Comment: If I only run this code: 
        String s3 = "1" + new String("1");
        String s5 = s3.intern(); System.out.println(s5 == s3); Result will be false in JUnit. If I move this code snippet from JUnit into public static void main(String[] args), result will be true. I have checked two version's bytecode, It would be the same. And I checked Constant Pool, Can't find anything like "11" before this line: String s4 = "11";

Comment: @Stylex Probably because JUnit is causing that sun.text.resources.FormatData class to load before your code.

Comment: @EJP I have downloaded jdk10, still got same result. you should try in junit instead of main method

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I have downloaded jdk10, still got same result. you should try in junit instead of main method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably `gg` is taken place in [String Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings) though I don't know how come, *maybe Junit did some prior things under the hood.* If a string literal is in string pool, it is referenced again in lieu of instantiating  again. That's why you get `true` in the second part of your code with `==` operator. *You should always use [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method for certain string comparison.*

Do you understand what [intern()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern())  method is actually doing?

String objects can be added to this pool using String's `intern()` method. For any two strings s and t, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is `true` if and only if `s.equals(t)` is true.

All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.

@Edit: OP said as comment,

> I checked *Constant Pool*, Can't find anything like `"11"` before this
>   line: `String s4 = "11"`;

You are not able to access the **string pool** from Java code, at least not in the HotSpot implementation of Java VM. So that's why you can't see `11` before `String s4 = "11"`

Comment: If I only run this code: 
        String s3 = "1" + new String("1");
        String s5 = s3.intern(); System.out.println(s5 == s3); Result will be false in JUnit. If I move this code snippet from JUnit into public static void main(String[] args), result will be true. I have checked two version's bytecode, It would be the same. And I checked Constant Pool, Can't find anything like "11" before this line: String s4 = "11";

Comment: @Stylex edited as well, _maybe `Junit` did some prior things under the hood._

Comment: OP probably checked constant pool of class, not string pool

Comment: @GotoFinal Yes, I wrote it to highlight where he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Like others says, you should use .equals to compare string, but if you wanted to know why exactly in this case you have different results then:

Each string literal is added to string pool by default and because `"1"` string is already used as literal in different class, then `.intern` is returning different instance, for `"g"` there are no other usages of such literal, so your one is the first added to the string pool - so `.intern` does not change anything in this case - as it returns this same instance as yours.
Same for `"11"` and `"gg"` string.
To be exact, on JDK 8 it seems to be used by `sun.text.resources.FormatData`. (both strings, `"1"` and `"11"`)

If you would add other class with `"g"` literal that would load before this one - you would get same results as for `"1"`.

Comment: If I only run this code: 
        String s3 = "1" + new String("1");
        String s5 = s3.intern(); System.out.println(s5 == s3); Result will be false in JUnit. If I move this code snippet from JUnit into public static void main(String[] args), result will be true. I have checked two version's bytecode, It would be the same. And I checked Constant Pool, Can't find anything like "11" before this line: String s4 = "11";

Comment: @Stylex Probably because JUnit is causing that `sun.text.resources.FormatData` class to load.