# Kotlin equality showing different output than expectation

Tags: kotlin, equality

Suppose I have a function:

```
 fun equality() {
        var a = "kotlin"
        var b = "kotlin"
        var c = a
        println(a==b)  //true
        println(a===b) //false
        println(a==c)  //true
        println(a===c) //true
    }
```

According to kotlin **===** a and b are different instance, So my expected output is:

```
true
false
true
true
```

But actually showing:

```
true
true
true
true
```

I can't understand how a===b is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*TL;DR: This is specific to strings on the JVM, they are managed in a pool and can be reused to save memory*

---

The JVM internally maintains a string pool which helps to save space for commonly used strings. You can do `java.lang.String("kotlin")`, i.e. using the standard Java `String` constructor, to bypass this technique but it's not recommended to not use the Kotlin mapped type `kotlin.String`.

Let me just crosspost this thread: [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)