# simple java boolean. Why does this return false?

Tags: java, boolean

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(endOther("Hiabc","abc"));

}

public static boolean endOther(String a , String b) {

    System.out.println(a.substring(a.length() - b.length()));
    return a.substring(a.length() - b.length()) == b;
}
}
```

basically it prints "abc" but then returns false and I don't know why

Comment: More fun reading about Java `String` handling: ["What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 1):

In Java dont use == to compare string, use equals()