# why these strings are not pointing to the same object in java?

Tags: java, string, pool

I know that if I have 2 string variables with the same value, they point to the same string object because of the java string pool.

Here is an example:

```
String test = "1234";
String test2 = "1234";
    
System.out.println(test == test2);
System.out.println("1234" == test2);
```

the output is the following:

```
true
true
```

But if I have the following code, it prints that they aren't the same object

```
String test = "1234";
int i = 1234;
String s = "" + i;
    
System.out.println(test == s);
System.out.println("1234" == s);
```

Output:

```
false
false
```

Anyone would explain to me the reason for that behavior, please?

Comment: `I know that if I have 2 string variables with the same value, they point to the same string object because of the java string pool.` No they do not.

Comment: It's because `i` isn't a constant expression according to Java's very narrow definition of that term.

Comment: The _string pool_ is for string constants. `"" + i` is **not** a string constant. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Comment: Try making `i` final.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @tkausl you mean, that two literal string initializations will produce two distinct objrcts?.. "no" is not really clear answer, imho.

Comment: @tkausl why do not?

Comment: @Sachin - Your proposed duplicate target doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @oltemo93 Let me ask you counter-question: "what makes you think they do/should"? Try to think about purpose of String Pool. Does it make sense to place ALL unique strings there? What if we write application which every second needs to read data from many sources and analyze it? If each data would be stored in string pool we would very quickly use all available memory. String Pool is cache for strings which have high chance of being reused bt application like string literals (things in code wrapped in `"..."`) since they can appear in loops or methods which can be called many times.

Comment: For instance if we have loop `while(condition){sout("your name: "); String name = scanner.nextLine();...}` it makes sense to store `"your name: "` String literal and reuse it for each iteration, but we don't really need to cache each `name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"" + i;` is not a constant expression, so it is not interned. If `i` were final or it was directly written as `"" + 1234`, then the value would be interned.

[§3.10.5. String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

[§15.28. Constant Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type and literals of type String (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4, §3.10.5)
>
>   Casts to primitive types and casts to type String (§15.16)
>
>   The unary operators +, -, ~, and ! (but not ++ or --) (§15.15.3, §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)
>
>   The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
>
>   The additive operators + and - (§15.18)
>
>   The shift operators >, and >>> (§15.19)
>
>   The relational operators , and >= (but not instanceof) (§15.20)
>
>   The equality operators == and != (§15.21)
>
>   The bitwise and logical operators &, ^, and | (§15.22)
>
>   The conditional-and operator && and the conditional-or operator || (§15.23, §15.24)
>
>   The ternary conditional operator ? : (§15.25)
>
>   Parenthesized expressions (§15.8.5) whose contained expression is a constant expression.
>
>   Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).
>
>   Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).